# warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What does mean? I get this error when trying to iterate through a file in Cocoa obj-c.

I can't find any information on the web.

Would appreciate some help. Thanks.

*EDIT*

I've been following this tutorial [(link)](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/core-data-starting-data.html) to preload Core Data. I've tried creating a Cococa application and have also tried doing this from within my iPhone app. I think all my setup code for Core Data is fine. Whenever this method is called I get EXEC BAD ACCESS.

```
- (void)loadInitialData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // name ZSTREET_1   ZSTREET_2   ZCITY   ZZIP    ZURL    ZTEL    latitude    longitude

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"placesdata" ofType:@"txt"];

    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path]; // reads file into memory as an NSString
    NSArray *lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"]; // each line, adjust character for line endings
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    for (NSString *line in lines)

    {   
        NSLog(line);

        NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:line];
        NSArray *parts = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
        // value mapping
        NSString *name = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *street_1 = [parts objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *street_2 = [parts objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *city = [parts objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *zip = [parts objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString *url = [parts objectAtIndex:5];

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        NSNumber *latitude = [f numberFromString:[parts objectAtIndex:6]];
        NSNumber *longitude = [f numberFromString:[parts objectAtIndex:7]];
        [f release];
        // splitting the parts to create the objects

        Place *place = (Place *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        Address *address = (Address *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        Location *location = (Location *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        // set attributes
        [place setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
        [address setValue:street_1 forKey:@"street_1"];
        [address setValue:street_2 forKey:@"street_2"];
        [address setValue:city forKey:@"city"];
        [address setValue:zip forKey:"@zip"];
        [address setValue:url forKey:@"url"];
        [location setValue:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
        [location setValue:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];

        // link the objects together
        [place setValue:address forKey:@"address"];
        [place setValue:location forKeyPath:@"address.location"];

        [string release];
    }
    NSLog(@"Done initial load");
    NSError *error; 
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", error);
    }
    [context release];
    [pool drain];


}
```

Comment: Cocoa, or Cocoa Touch? I notice you tagged the question as [iphone].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong and should produce a compiler warning:

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:line];
```

The method `initWithUTF8String:` expects an UTF-8 encoded C string and not a `NSString` object.

Before you continue you should fix **all** compiler warnings! And you also should check that the `parts` array actually contains as many objects as you expect. You also need to use a format string with NSLog, you might even crash there if your line contains any `%` characters.

Comment: apski: Moreover, if you already have an NSString object, you don't need to create an NSString object from it.

Comment: Thanks all! It was in fact the line encoding that was causing the problem.

Comment: That's great for HIS problem, but what does the error mean?!  That is, I've got the same error message in completely different code.  How to debug?

(No compiler warnings or analyze warnings, and I'm an experienced iOS developer.  I just haven't seen this one before.)

Thanks!

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 29):

For other people running into this problem with entirely different code, this is a bit of a red herring.

The warning is from the debugger itself. The debugger creates a struct containing info for each object in the system. After the EXC_BAD_ACCESS, it tried to create one of these but was unable to. Note that this is a warning and not an error so it may even be expected in situations like this.

In any event, the details surrounding this don't matter. You've got to find the source of your EXC_BAD_ACCESS. A common cause is trying to access an object after it has been released.

Answer (score 4):

For someone who comes across this in the future, I got this problem because I was doing this too much:

```
NSString* aString = @"";

for(int i=0; i<someLargeNumber; i++) {
    aString = [aString stringByAppendingFormat:@"..."];
}
```

Once I switched to using `NSMutableString`, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to run into `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on a fairly regular basis (which is not a good thing), because we haven't enabled ARC yet.

I find the best way to track those errors down by using the Profiler in Zombie modus. This post shows you how to "hunt for zombies":

[How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/8863063#8863063)