# app crash with button IB

Tags: iphone

When i add a button to my cell like this, it's work fine, but when i add it in IB, i have a crash with the log above. Any Idea ? thanks four your answers

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(goToGeoloc)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(218.0, 8.0, 45.0, 45.0);
[cell addSubview:button];
```

`the crash log :

```
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x02c65a93 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x005596c8 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#3  0x0055bb4a in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#4  0x0055a6f7 in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#5  0x00747070 in _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver ()
#6  0x02aebd1b in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#7  0x02a80987 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#8  0x02a49c17 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#9  0x02a49280 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#10 0x02a491a1 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#11 0x031f72c8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#12 0x031f738d in GSEventRun ()
#13 0x004ddb58 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Comment: Are you creating custom tableview cell?

Comment: Yes.i am creating a custom tableView Cell

Comment: what is cell here? is it a tableview cell ?

Comment: Then create the button in custom tableview cell or illustrate more about your problem.

Comment: when i create it programmaticaly, it's good. but when i create it by IB, ihave a crash

Comment: Then why are you using IB , if it's working fine through praogrmmatically

Comment: When you use it through IB, you must be creating a CustomCell.xib and adding it on the cell, nothing else....can you post that code, where you add the custom cell in your table View?

Comment: See the second answer in this post: [The warning is from the debugger itself.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637714/warning-attempting-to-create-use-block-in-frame-variable-with-block-that-isnt)

Answer (score 1):

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```