# My iphone app crashes the first time i open the project

Tags: iphone, crash

It crashes only one time and then it works normally.

Here is the project:
http://www.mediafire.com/?p0dy7g5ozkl69jt

Comment: Can you post the crash report please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a memory issue trying to access a released `NSURL` in your `GetXML` class...
There:

```
- (void)main {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    >> NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
...
```

To diagnose these, make use of NSZombiesEnabled, [explained there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/nszombieenabled-in-latest-xcode).

To fix your crash, make sure you `retain` or `copy` your url in your GetXML class :

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)newURL delegate:(id <GetXMLDelegate>)newDelegate
{
    self = [super init];
    url = [newURL copy]; // there
    delegate = newDelegate;

    return self;
}
```

and to avoid a memory leak, make sure your release that URL

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [url release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Untested code, but should work... You should re-read [Apple documentation about memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf)... ;)