# UITableView crashes when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've been attempting to create my own app for a band by my friends, and I've been experimenting with using a custom TableViewCell for news articles that appear on the website.  My main objective is to get all of the data from the website, store it in a NSMutableArray, and then display that in my custom cells.

The app runs fine when it loads the first 5-6 cells.  However, when I begin to scroll, the app crashes.  I've pinpointed the in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  Using GDB, I've also come to find out that after I create my NSMutableArray data and once the program runs, after scrolling, my array seems to be autoreleased.  I'm not sure why this happens.  Here's what I have for my code thus far:

In HomeViewController.h:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
    NSArray *results;
    NSMutableArray *titles;
    NSMutableArray *dates;
    NSMutableArray *entries;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *titles;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dates;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *entries;

@end
```

In HomeViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while((i+1) != endIndex){   
    NSString *curr_title = [[NSString alloc] init]; 
    NSString *curr_date = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *curr_entry = [[NSString alloc] init];

    //do some character iterations across a string

    [titles addObject:curr_title];
    [dates addObject:curr_date];
    [entries addObject:curr_entry];

    [curr_title release];
    [curr_date release];
    [curr_entry release];
}
}
```

//more code here, removed

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCell";


NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell"
                                owner:self options:nil];
//  cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell = (NewsCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

}
NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"%d", titles.count);
cell.cellTitle.text = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.datePosted.text = [dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.preview.text = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Again, the first 5-6 cells show up.  Once I scroll, I tried doing `po titles` and got this error:

`Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000009
0x011b309b in objc_msgSend ()`

I've tried allocating the arrays in `initWithNibName:` but that didn't seem to do much.  I've tried moving all the code in `viewDidLoad:` and then calling `[super viewDidLoad]` and it just produced the same results as well.  Sorry this is so long, but I figured people needed to see my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you posted.  Try [enabling the NSZombieEnabled environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4).  This prevents objects from being released so that when your application "crashes" you can determine which object caused the problem.

Also, instead of looping through array of objects returned by `loadNibNamed:owner:options`, you should assign the desired object to an `IBOutlet` property of your class.  See [Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) for an example.

---

The following is extracted from the new code you posted:

```
NSString *curr_title = [[NSString alloc] init];

//do some character iterations across a string

[titles addObject:curr_title];

[curr_title release];
```

NSString is not mutable (as is NSMutableString).  Are you intentionally adding empty strings to the titles array?

---

In response to your comment:  `stringByAppendingString` creates a new autoreleased NSString object.

```
NSString *curr_title = [[NSString alloc] init];

// this leaks the original NSString object (curr_title no longer points to it);
// curr_title now points to a new, autoreleased NSString
curr_title = [curr_title stringByAppendingString:@"..."];

[titles addObject:curr_title];

// releasing the autoreleased NSString will cause your application to crash!
[curr_title release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did try using NSZombiesEnabled, but it didn't provide any information at all oddly enough.  I used Instruments and it did say that there was "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x5e70870."  It pointed to something that got autoreleased, so I'm currently looking into that.  It still seems like my arrays are getting released somehow.

Comment: Also check that the objects that you are adding to the arrays are not being over-released.

Comment: I added some more code (edit above).  I don't think they're being over-released, but somehow in the event that they are (I'm still trying to get the hang of Objective-c!), I'll definitely fix that.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting, because I've debugged the arrays before and I get full strings.  This could be because through iteration, I append a string as such : `curr_title = [curr_title stringByAppendingString:c];` Could it be because of this that I'm losing strings?  For the record, c is an NSString version of a character.  I've changed it now to [curr_title appendString:c]. I'll see what happens from here.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is; see my updated answer.  Also, you can call `appendString:` on an NSMutableString, but not on an NSString.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you said that, I figured pointers were going to be off!  I also fixed another error where I was allocated and initialized c as an NSMutableString, but then sent it `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:]` which caused it to autorelease. Later near the end of the code, I released it, which caused my program to crash.  But it's fixed now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help!  But just to be clear, `stringWithFormat:` doesn't cause the NSString object it is sent to to be autoreleased, it returns a *new* autoreleased NSString.

Comment: Ah I see.  That just seems like it would waste a lot of space for a while since you keep creating new strings, but I guess since they autorelease, they're reclaimed fairly fast?

Comment: If you're creating a hundreds of NSString objects in a tight loop you would want to avoid autorelease.  However, in most situations the benefits of immutability with respect to multithreading are worth the tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the implementation of NewsCell, all your properties there being retained?

Also, any reason HomeViewController is subclassing UIViewController and not UITableViewController?

And this should work just fine:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: No those arrays aren't being over-retained.  The synthesized setter method isn't being used.

Comment: It's not necessary to subclass UITableViewController to use a UITableView within a UIViewController.  UITableViewController can be convenient but it comes at the price of flexibility.

Comment: Nice catch; I assume you meant to comment on my post.  Fixed!

Comment: I did but I don't have that option yet.

Comment: Thanks for the response Leehro!  I saw multiple articles stating that you could do the for() loop or the `[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0]`, hence that's why I had the latter commented out for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

*EXC_BAD_ACCESS* is a sure sign that one of your objects is getting over released (or wasn't retained properly). **NSZombieEnabled** is your friend here, just as titaniumdecoy suggests - figuring out what object is being over released is half the battle. Just be sure to turn it off before releasing the app, because (as titaniumdecoy pointed out) it prevents objects from getting released.

I usually use a combination of NSZombieEnabled and well placed breakpoints (so I can walk through the code till it crashes) to figure out where the problem is cropping up in the code. Then it's usually a simple matter of backtracking to figure out where the object was over released.