# Program received SIGABRT when using variable except NSLOG

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

Hey guys, I'm receiving a SIGABRT when trying to use an instance variable for anything but an NSLOG :

```
//Class_X.H
@interface MeldingController : UIViewController 
{   
    NSString *refURLAsString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *refURLAsString;

//Class_X.M
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.refURLAsString = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.refURLAsString);//Successfully outputs the ReferenceURL string
}

-(void)function_abc
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.refURLAsString);//Successfully outputs the ReferenceURL string
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.refURLAsString]; //SIGABRT
    //Or even trying to make another string using refUrlAsString 
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]init];
    string = self.refURLAsString;//SIGABRT
}
```

iPhone Simulator iOS version 4.3, Xcode 4.

Any ideas anyone? cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `refURLAsString` is of type `NSString *`, but `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]` should return a `NSURL *` instance [according to the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html). You want:

```
self.refURLAsString = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] absoluteString];
```

The reason why the `NSLog` works is because it calls the `description` method on each object that is to be printed via the `%@` sequence, and that does return a string. But `refURLAsString` is pointing to a NSURL instead of a NSString, and that makes `[NSURL URLWithString:self.refURLAsString];` crash.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string =[refURLAsString copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is screwing up refURLAsString. I can't tell you how from the posted code. Activate [NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly whats the issue is, but try `string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.refURLAsString];` and see if it crashes here too

Answer (score 0):

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.refURLAsString];

no need to alloc here