# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access, didselectrowatindexpath

I have overwritten my `UITableViewController` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method the following way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoListViewController *photosViewController = [[PhotoListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    NSLog(@"Let's see what we got %d", [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);

    Person *person = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    photosViewController.person = person;
    photosViewController.title = [person.name stringByAppendingString:@"'s Photos"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photosViewController animated:YES];

    [photosViewController release];
}
```

Whenever I try to access the `fetchedResultsController` I get the crash, I set it here:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person = %@", person];
        fetchedResultsController = [[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Photo" withPredicate:predicate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And I only release it in my `dealloc` method

Comment: Please post any relevant crash information. Console output, crash log, and make sure NSZombieEnabled is on

Comment: I get no crash info, it just halts in my main on this line int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); and says EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Can you tell me how I set NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: Ok, I set NSZombieEnabled and my fetchedObjects are not there it seems, let me check a little further

Comment: The issue was simply not retaining fetchedResultsController, but NSZombieEnabled will help you find issues like this faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like your autorelease pool is getting drained before your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is called. Did you try retaining the fetchedResultsController like so:

```
fetchedResultsController = [[[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Photo" withPredicate:predicate] retain];
```

Comment: If you check the 2nd block of code I posted I do that in my initWithStyle method

Comment: The key there is the call to retain, your fetchedResultsController is not guaranteed to live long enough to be useful outside of your init method unless you retain it.

Comment: I thought setting the property as (nonatomic, retain) did that

Comment: You are not using the property unless you specify `self`. `self.fetchedResultsController` would not require you to retain because it would of used the property instead of the instance variable like you are now.