# Getting EXC Bad Access With Xcode 4.1GM

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I just opened my project with Xcode 4.1GM (was using 4.0.2 before).  When I enter a number in a textfield I get an EXC Bad Access error but the log doesn't provide any info so I can't figure out whats going on.  Is there something new in the 4.1 GM that messed this up?

Crash is happening in main.m file at line `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

This is a code that pushes the view and keyboard which is crashing:

```
- (IBAction)weightButtonPressed
{
    [self.weightView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.weightView];

    BOOL isKgs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isKgs"];
    if (isKgs)
    {
        self.weightLabel.text = @"0 kgs";   
    }
    else
    {
        self.weightLabel.text = @"0 lbs";   
    }
    self.weightTextField.text = nil;

    UIBarButtonItem *acceptButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismssPickerSetWeight)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = acceptButton;
    [acceptButton release];

    [weightTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    self.weightSelectedString = self.weightTextField.text;
    self.weightTextField.hidden = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2
                     animations:^
    {[weightTextField becomeFirstResponder]; [self.weightView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];} 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the stack trace where you crash include `[AppleSpell init]`?

It's a known bug on Lion with Xcode 4.1 GM **seed**.

But you installed the final version already, right? Check About Xcode. It should say **4B110**. It will probably say **4B95**. The Xcode final installer doesn't properly upgrade the seed.

**You need to completely uninstall Xcode 4.1 GM seed first for the Xcode installer to do its job.** See the `About Xcode.pdf` in your /Developer folder.

If you're not on the 4.1 branch for whatever reason, you could work around this by turning off autocorrect in your `viewDidLoad`, but make sure you're using a **final** build of Xcode for public releases.

Answer (score 1):

You generally get bad access errors due to over-released objects. I would recommend running your code in instruments with the Zombies profile.

You can do this by holding the run button in Xcode until a list appears, and then selecting 'Profile'.

Comment: For some reason instruments is not working.  it is just freezing up on me.

Comment: You could try setting `NSZombieEnabled` instead. [Instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4).

Comment: I already have NSZombies on, and I restarted my computer and instruments still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I got instruments working one time and the app crashed as usual at the number input but there are no leaks recorded.

Comment: You are not looking for leaks, you are looking for zombies. A zombie is a deallocated object (ref count drops to 0, then you reference the object again), and Instruments should track them for you. [This link](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2011/02/hunting-down-zombies-in-ios-apps/) has a brief overview of how to use the Zombies instrument.