# iOS start Background Thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uikit, core-foundation

I have a small sqlitedb in my iOS device. When a user presses a button, I fetch the data from sqlite & show it to user.

This fetching part I want to do it in a background thread (to not block the UI main thread). I do this like so -

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getResultSetFromDB:) withObject:docids];`

After the fetching & a little bit of processing, I need to update the UI. But since (as a good practice) we should not perform UI updation from background threads. I call a `selector` on mainthread like so -

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showResults) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

But my App crashes in the first step. i.e. starting a background thread. Is this not a way to start background threads in iOS?

**UPDATE 1:** After `[self performSelectorInBackground....` I get this stacktrace, no info what so ever -

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I even tried, starting a background thread like so - 
`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getResultSetFromDB:) toTarget:self withObject:docids];` but still I get same stacktrace.

Just so that I clarify, when I perform this operation on main thread everything runs smooth...

**UPDATE 3** This is the method I am trying to run from background

```
- (void)getResultSetFromDB:(NSMutableArray *)toProceessDocids
{
    SpotMain *mirror = [[SpotMain alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *filteredDocids = toProceessDocids;

    if(![gMediaBucket isEqualToString:@""])
        filteredDocids = [mirror FetchDocIdsForMediaBucketWithDocID:filteredDocids mBucket:gMediaBucket numRes:-1];
    if(![gMediaType isEqualToString:@""])
        filteredDocids = [mirror FetchDocIdsForMediaType:filteredDocids mediaType:gMediaType numRes:-1];
    if(![gPlatform isEqualToString:@""])
        filteredDocids = [mirror FetchDocIdsForPlatformID:filteredDocids platformId:@"1" numRes:-1];

    self.resultSet = [mirror FetchObjectFromDocid:filteredDocids];
    [filteredDocids release];
    [mirror release];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showResults) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    return;
}
```

Comment: What error / crash log do you get?

Comment: Please see my updates...

Comment: Can you please show the method you are calling in the background? And make sure the object `docids` is retained.

Comment: yes, `docids` are `retain`. I have put it in `.h` as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *docids;`

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`;  that should just be `resultSetFromDB:`

Answer (score 273, accepted):

If you use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` to spawn a new thread, then the performed selector is responsible for setting up the new thread's autorelease pool, run loop and other configuration details – see ["Using NSObject to Spawn a Thread"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW13) in Apple's *Threading Programming Guide*.

You'd probably be better off using [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), though:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self getResultSetFromDB:docids];
});
```

GCD is a newer technology, and is more efficient in terms of memory overhead and lines of code.

---

**Updated** with a hat tip to [Chris Nolet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746890/chris-nolet), who suggested a change that makes the above code simpler and keeps up with Apple's latest GCD code examples.

Comment: cool! didn't know this. Does this apply to `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector....` also?

Comment: Yes. Per the Apple docs, calling `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` "is the same as if you called the `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` method of `NSThread` with the current object, selector, and parameter object as parameters."

Comment: Is there a difference between `(unsigned long)NULL` and `0` in this matter?

Comment: @Sti from apple Dev [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1): Note: The second argument to the dispatch_get_global_queue function is reserved for future expansion. For now, you should always pass 0 for this argument.

Comment: Should I then use performSelectorOnMainThread to update UI with operation results or there is more consistent way to update UI with GCD?

Comment: Also, you can change the flag from  *DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT* to *DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND*

Answer (score 11):

Well that's pretty easy actually with GCD. A typical workflow would be something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // Perform async operation
        // Call your method/function here
        // Example:
        // NSString *result = [anObject calculateSomething];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update UI
                    // Example:
                    // self.myLabel.text = result;
                });
    });
```

For more on GCD you can take a look into [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

Enable [NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/4917557#4917557) to know which object is being released and then accessed.
Then check if the `getResultSetFromDB:` has anything to do with that. Also check if `docids` has anything inside and if it is being retained.

This way you can be sure there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Please copy the line you used that run smoothly on main thread.

Comment: I use this from main thread & atleast it hits that method instead of abruptly crashing - `[self getResultSetFromDB:docids];`

Comment: have you enabled what i told you?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this line:  _SpotMain *mirror = [[SpotMain alloc] init];_ and tell me if its hit and, if tehn, which line crashes. Enable zombies please so we can get a clear error log.

Comment: yes, I have enabled zombies. I get this - `
2011-08-14 12:49:42.697 FLO[16211:707] *** -[FMResultSet release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2bff80
2011-08-14 12:49:42.697 FLO[16211:1607] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x2c0cc0 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`. Also when I try to call this method from background thread I do not reach `SpotMain *mirror...`, It crashes soon after entering the background thread...

Comment: This is not a zombie-related problem. The problem is that, if you create a new thread using `performSelectorInBackground:withObject`, your new thread doesn't have an autorelease pool (unless you create one manually). Hence the error message about autoreleasing an object with no pool in place.

Answer (score 2):

The default sqlite library that comes with iOS is not compiled using the SQLITE_THREADSAFE macro on. This could be a reason why your code crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.x answer:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        self.getResultSetFromDB(docids)
    }
```