# if loop that running asynchoursly

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Hello everyone, I want to create if loop that running asynchoursly with this code:

```
NSString *care = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/untitled.txt"]];
if (care == @"ONRED") { //untitled.txt = ONRED
   [red_on setHidden:NO];
   [red_off setHidden:YES];
}
```

How I can run the if statement like a loop?

Comment: I dont no. there are vay to run void asynchrously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you can put those statements in a method and call `performSelectorInBackground`:

```
(void)asyncMethod {
    NSString *care = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/untitled.txt"]];
    if (care == @"ONRED") { //untitled.txt = ONRED
        [red_on setHidden:NO];
        [red_off setHidden:YES];
    }
}

// in some other method
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(asyncMethod) withObject:nil];
```

Another option is to use the grand central dispatch (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055424/ios-start-background-thread)):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    NSString *care = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/untitled.txt"]];
        if (care == @"ONRED") { //untitled.txt = ONRED
            [red_on setHidden:NO];
            [red_off setHidden:YES];
        }
});
```