# How to run another thread and using that thread run timer to repeat process?

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsthread

Hi i want to start a timer with another thread and want to repeat process in that thread. i had tried but it doesn't work.

my code snippet is given below

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(setupTimerThread) toTarget:self   withObject:nil];


    -(void)setupTimerThread
    {
    NSLog(@"inside setup timer thread");
    // self.startTiemr = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
    startTiemr = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self    selector:@selector(triggerTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
     [runLoop addTimer:startTiemr forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [runLoop run];       
}
```

can anyone suggest me a proper way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055424/ios-start-background-thread

Comment: thanks for your attention but i want to start a thread that run a timer and timer will repeat after 30 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import "TimePassViewController.h"

@interface TimePassViewController ()

@end

@implementation TimePassViewController
{
    NSTimer *timer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourmethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


    NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(yourmethod)
                                                   object:nil];
    [myThread start];  // Actually create the thread

}





-(void)yourmethod
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSRunLoop *TimerRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [TimerRunLoop run];
    }
   //timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerMethod
{
    NSLog(@"aaaaaaaaaaaa");
    //[timer invalidate];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to run it on a separate thread not on main thread

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
NStimer  *uptimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(bachground_todaylist) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 -(void)bachground_todaylist
    {

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourmethod) withObject:nil];


    }
you wants to stop proces
```

[uptimer invalidate];

Comment: performselectorinbackground will stop after all (yourmethod) done?

Comment: no only stop uptimer invalidate
if you wants to stop then set timer repeat NO

Comment: but if it repeats after every 1 second each time new thread created

Comment: i want to create a single another thread and repeats its process after every 20 seconds and when i click stop button it should stop.and in this process after every 20 seconds webservice will called but in this process application should not jamm on that view controller

Comment: jamm only view is refresh or reload

Comment: when url request will start sending and getting response view will not allow to go to another view and another function

Comment: try this method :[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
remove performSelectorInBackground method

Comment: thanks for reply, i used this method but it runs as earlier methods