# iOS: starting Long-Running Tasks in foreground

Tags: ios

What is the proper way to handle continuos tasks like location tracking?
If i understood [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) correctly, Long-Running Tasks suppose to be started on app going to background.

Can I just run the location tracking (as Long-Running Task) on app start and run it continuously until user will explicitly disable it?

Comment: In case of Location Tracking you can obviously run it continuously but smartly using proper accuracy and filter so that it doesn't require to update so often as running location manager continuously will cause a lot of battery usage.

Comment: @iphonic, i know. It was just an example. In fact i'll be dealing with BLE, but this may rise more questions, so i've used Location Tracking for sake of simplicity. So, can i run the long-running task while app in foreground? Is it violating any stupid rules or whatever apple's restrictions?

Comment: Don't you just want to work with a background thread to deal with these things while your app is in the foreground?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus - probably, that's what i want. I do not know how to do that, as i'm react-native developer. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) shows only how to start it at quit time. And i haven't found any more useful examples in the web. Do you have one?

Comment: @stkvtflw: Something like this should probably still work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055424/ios-start-background-thread
For longrunning tasks when your app goes to the background you can do something like you already read in the apple docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html. If you have more specific requests I could make a less general solution for you, since these examples are pretty basic.