# iOS NSData cast to NSMutableData memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, nsdata

I have a problem in iOS development.

I pass the `NSData` and some params to the function.

```
 // this time memory is about 54 MB
 + (NSData*) doFileData : (NSData*) fileData andFileName:(NSString*) fileName{

   NSMutableData *fileContentData = [NSMutableData dataWithData: fileData];
   // after doing the cast line, the memory is about 99 MB
    .....
 }
```

When I cast the `NSData` to the `NSMutableData` , the memory usage from 54MB upper to the 99 MB.

How can I cast the `NSData` to the `NSMutableData` using limit memory function?

thank you very much.

Comment: you can use GCD.. background thread for NSData conversion ---> https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055574/4970453

Answer (score 0):

You could try use the method `+ (id)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataReadingOptions)readOptionsMask error:(NSError **)errorPtr;`.For the second paramter,you could use NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe.

Comment: If I got the NSData is not from path(maybe the NSData is From a large NSData split out), it can't use  the datawithcontensOfFile method..