# Singleton's property memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, properties

I'm trying to write my little app and experiencing some memory management problems.
At first, I have `Game` singleton object with property:

```
//Game.h
@interface Game : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) MapBuildingsLayer *mapBuildingsLayer;

+(Game *) game;
-(BOOL) addObject:(NSString *) objName At:(CGPoint) pt;

@end
```

where `MapBuildingsLayer` is just cocos2d `CCLayer` instance

```
//Game.m
@implementation Game
@synthesize mapBuildingsLayer = _mapBuildingsLayer;

static Game *instance = nil;

+ (Game *)game {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[Game alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

-(BOOL) addObject:(NSString *)objName At:(CGPoint)pt
{
    if([objName isEqualToString:OBJ_TYPE_PIT])
    {
        if([[Game game].mapBuildingsLayer addPitAt:pt]) //app crashes here
        {
            [self toggleConstructionMode];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

In `MapBuildingsLayer.m`'s `init` method I use `Game`'s `mapBuildingsLayer` property to store a reference to this CCLayer instance in my singleton (for future use in other methods):

```
//MapBuildingsLayer.m
@implementation MapBuildingsLayer

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        [Game game].mapBuildingsLayer = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I call `Game`'s `addObject:objName At:` method, my app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
How I must declare property in `Game` singleton to use it from other places in my app's lifetime?

Comment: Try enabling NSZombieEnabled and see what extra info that gives you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

Comment: @Rengers Enabling zombies doesn't add any extra lines to debug log.

Comment: where does mapBuildingLayer get alloc init'ed?

Comment: Where is [MapsBuildingLayer node] being called?

Comment: @crackity_jones: then how I can store a reference to `MapBuildingsLayer` in my singleton `Game`? And how can I access it later for sending messages to it?

Comment: @bryanmac @crackity_jones: `[MapsBuildingLayer node]` is called in `[MapLayer init]`, then `MapsBuildingLayer` is added as child to `MapLayer` and `MapLayer` is finally added as child to `GameScreenScene`.

Comment: @Antonr I just added a bit more detail to my answer in response to this. I think it will get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you all, I've found my problem, it was in `MapBuildingsLayer addPitAt:` method, poor initialization of some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically don't use the singleton in the class itself, try changing

```
        if([[Game game].mapBuildingsLayer addPitAt:pt]) //app crashes here
```

to

```
        if([self.mapBuildingsLayer addPitAt:pt]) //app crashes here
```

You should be using [Game game] external to the class to get into the singleton instance of your class and call its methods, but internal to the class you would just refer to it as self like normal.

Typically if you're going to use a game singleton this isn't how you'd use it. Try thinking of it like this with a giant state machine, Create a CCScene subclass which will initialize all of your respective CCLayer subclasses and control them. Then from the statemachine you can load the appropriate initializing its scene and that will create everything under it.

In your applicationDidFinishLaunching method you simply have your singleton object load your first scene. I'd really recommend checking out the [Learning Cocos2d Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321735625) as it covers this singleton state engine very well and I think would clear up all your questions.

Bottom line is have the state engine load the scene which loads the layers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But changing `[Game game]` to `[self]` didn't fixed crash.

Comment: Guarantee your mapBuildingsLayer property is nil at this point.

Comment: Yes, this property initionally is `nil`, then after initialization of `MapBuildingsLayer` it's set to proper address (I've just checked it through debug). I mean, my instance of `MapBuildingsLayer` have address `0xAABBCC` for example and value of `[Game game].mapBuildingsLayer` also set to `0xAABBCC` at the moment of crash.

Answer (score 0):

No where in your code i am seeing your mapBuildingsLayer initialized. I hope before returning your instance you should also do

```
instance.mapBuildingsLayer = [CCLayer alloc] init];
```

Comment: Of course I have the following line:
`MapBuildingsLayer *buildings = [MapBuildingsLayer node];`
in my code. My `MapBuildingsLayer` instance is initialized and working properly (catching touch events for example).

Comment: @Saran: Although you are right, this is probably not the cause of the crash. If it's not initialized it will be nil, and sending messages to nil won't cause a crash. By the way, this code should be more along the lines of `instance.mapBuildingsLayer = [[[MapBuildingsLayer alloc] init] autorelease]`;

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are assigning the mapBuildingsLayer is wrong. Remove `[Game game].mapBuildingsLayer = self` from  your MapBuildingsLayer init method and instead add the following inside `Game` init method:

```
self.mapBuildingsLayer = [[MapBuildingsLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
```

now it is initialized inside your singleton `init` method so you can access it simply as `[Game game].mapBuildingsLayer` anywhere outside the `Game` class. If this doesnt work try posting what `addPitAt:` does.

hope this helps