# NSURLRequest: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: php, iphone, ios, memory-leaks, nsurlrequest

I'm building an application with loads content from an PHP file. I have 4 views with loads content from 4 different PHP files. For each view controller i'm using the following code:

```
//
//  turmaAViewController.m
//  SamplePad
//
//  Created by Mateus Nunes on 25/09/11.
//  Copyright 2011 NBM Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "turmaAViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation turmaAViewController

@synthesize messageList;
@synthesize studentImageView;
@synthesize imageText;

//###############################################################################
//############################################################ DEVICE ORIENTATION
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){ 
        return YES;
    }
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        return YES;
    }else
        return NO;
}

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                           CUSTOM VIEW INITIALIZATION                                      #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        lastId = 0;
        chatParser = NULL;
    }
    return self;
}

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                           DEALLOC - MEMORY RELEASE                                       #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(void)dealloc {
    [messageList release];
    [super dealloc];
}

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                           DISPLAY PHP FILE INTEGRATION                                   #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(void)getNewMessages {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/SPA/turmaa.php?past=%ld&t=%ld",lastId, time(0) ];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];  

    if (conn){  
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];  
    }else{}  

}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                                FETCHING PRAGMAS                                          #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(void)timerCallback {
    [timer release];
    [self getNewMessages];
}

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                             CONNECTION PRAGMAS                                           #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}  
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}  
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  {  

    if (chatParser)
        [chatParser release];

    if (messages == nil)

        messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    chatParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
    [chatParser setDelegate:self];
    [chatParser parse];

    [receivedData release];  
    [messageList reloadData];

    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector: @selector(timerCallback)]];
    //[invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(timerCallback)];
    //timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
}  

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                         PARSING THE MESSAGE XML FILE LIST                                #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"message"] ) {

        msgAdded = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"added"] retain];
        msgId = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

        msgAluno     = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        msgMatricula = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        msgCpf       = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        msgImage     = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        msgCC   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        inAluno   = NO;
        inMatricula   = NO;
        inCpf  = NO;
        inImage  = NO;
        inCC  = NO;
    }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"aluno"]     )  { inAluno = YES;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"matricula"] )  { inMatricula = YES;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"cpf"]       )  { inCpf = YES;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]     )  { inImage = YES;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"CC"]  )  { inCC = YES;}


}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ( inAluno )      { [msgAluno appendString:string]; }
    if ( inMatricula )  { [msgMatricula appendString:string]; }
    if ( inCpf )        { [msgCpf appendString:string]; }
    if ( inImage )      { [msgImage appendString:string];}
    if ( inCC )         { [msgCC appendString:string];}

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"message"] ) {

        [messages addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:msgAdded,@"added",msgAluno,@"aluno",msgMatricula,@"matricula",msgCpf,@"cpf",msgImage,@"image",msgCC,@"CC",nil]];

        [[messages reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

        lastId = msgId;

        [msgAdded release];
        [msgAluno release];
        [msgMatricula release];
        [msgCpf release];
        [msgImage release];
        [msgCC release];

    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"aluno"]     ) { inAluno = NO;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"matricula"] ) { inMatricula = NO;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"cpf"]       ) { inCpf = NO;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]     ) { inImage = NO;}
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"CC"]  ) { inCC = NO;}
}

//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                         PARSING FINISHED - START DISPLAYING                              #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return ( messages == nil ) ? 0 : [messages count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.messageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newsCustomCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"newsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *timeDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    timeDate.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"added"];

    UILabel *userL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    userL.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"aluno"];

    UILabel *textL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    textL.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"matricula"];

    UILabel *textL2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    textL2.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"cpf"];

    UILabel *imageL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    imageL.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"image"];

    UILabel *videoL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
    videoL.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"CC"];

    UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView *) [cell viewWithTag:7];
    NSString *urlAddress = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *selectTime = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"added"];

    NSString *selectUser = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"aluno"];

    NSString *selectMessage = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"matricula"];

    NSString *selectMessage2 = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"cpf"];

    NSString *selectImage = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"image"];

    NSString *selectVideo = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"CC"];

    dvController.selectedTime = selectTime;
    dvController.selectedUser = selectUser;
    dvController.selectedImage = selectImage;
    dvController.selectedMessage = selectMessage;
    dvController.selectedMessage2 = selectMessage2;
    dvController.selectedVideo = selectVideo;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}


//##############################################################################################################################
//#################                         PARSING FINISHED - START DISPLAYING                              #################//
//##############################################################################################################################
-(void)viewDidLoad {    
    messageList.dataSource = self;
    messageList.delegate = self;

    [messageList release];


    [self getNewMessages];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


@end
```

First when i build one view with this code and tested it had worked well, no problems. But when i added this code to the others views the application started crashing, "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" Error! Because of this i suppose i need to kill the request when i run out of my view, but how can i do this or if you identify another problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a hint, not the answer. EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when a method is called on an object that has been released. To see which object is being called, you will have to enable Zombies. To enable zombies in xcode 4, see [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4).