# iPhone cocos2d [super onExit]; causing crash when touch event occurs.

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, function-exit

Please help!

When I use:

```
-(void) onExit {
[super onExit];
}
```

my app crashes if the screen is touched in the next scene after onExit is called. The error points to:

```
-(void) touches:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event withTouchType:(unsigned int)idx
```

within "CCTouchDispatcher.m". However, when I remove the [super onExit]; line, it doesn't crash.

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[super onExit] is necessary, otherwise touch handling is disabled - which explains why it won't crash if you remove it.

You have a memory issue, most likely some object has been released without being removed from CCTouchDispatcher. [NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4) is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll see what I can find out from NSZombieEnable and let you know if it works.