# EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception - how to track it?

Tags: iphone, exception, exc-bad-access

I'm testing/debugging my app in the simulator. Once in a while (I can't track down any specifics) I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception, but when it happens, line

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

in the `main.c` is being highlighted.  There's nothing in the log to indicate what causes the error (nothing at all, in fact).  What can I do to track this down, to understand what causes the error (and, naturally, fix it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you are sending a message to a object, that is overreleased, and thus deallocated.

Run your app with [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), that should give you the object, that doesn't exist anymore.

should be helpful: [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a memory corruption issue. Try running it as Profile/Analyze (as opposed to Run), most likely it'll find memory leaks, memory corruption for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I ran through "Analyze" - and it only gave me a few "Possible memory leak" warnings, but nothing else.  Tried running through "Profile" - but the app simply dies.