# Posting to Facebook Wall - iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to create a class that will handle contain all Facebook methods, and to call methods from other classes when required;

And this is how i am calling these methods (from a another viewController)

I have added a button and on its click event i add the following code;

```
FBClass *fb= [[FBClass alloc] init];
[fb fbLogin];
[fb accesstokenDetails];
```

This program works perfectly, i asks the user for the credentials and then ask the user to type something to share, and it also post to the FB wall. But the program crashes with the sharing screen;

What should i do to prevent this ?

Comment: try enabling zombies and seing why you are getting a bad_access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Comment: Did you enable breakboints for all exceptions in Xcode? Maybe it helps if you take a look at my source code: https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare/blob/dev/iOS/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare.m