# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when opening modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm having a problem with my iPhone App, I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I had some memory leaks, but these are now fixed, so I'm not sure whats going on. I realise that I haven't provide a lot of information, but I really don't know whats happening.

The initial screen opens up where I have a number of buttons. Tapping on the first button, which runs the following code and opens up a modal view:

```
-(IBAction)newWorkoutButton
{
    newWorkoutViewController .loadedFromRootViewController = @"YES";
    [self presentModalViewController:newWorkoutViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The screen freezes and the is in the code below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Method getDistanceFrom = class_getInstanceMethod([CLLocation class], @selector(getDistanceFrom:));
    class_addMethod([CLLocation class], @selector(distanceFromLocation:), method_getImplementation(getDistanceFrom), method_getTypeEncoding(getDistanceFrom));

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); // ERROR HAPPENING HERE
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Enable "zombie" mode and run your program again - you will see exactly what/where the error occurs.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4 on how to enable this mode.

Comment: Out of interest what are you trying to achieve with the `class_getInstanceMethod`/`class_addMethod` stuff?

Comment: you may be releasing some autoreleased object .. It will be better if you can give the crashlog ..

Comment: Where is your newWorkoutViewController allocated?

Answer (score 1):

Like Aleks suggested you can try to find the zombie like this:

I find this alternative more convenient:

1. Click the "Run Button Dropdown"
2. From the list choose `Profile`
3. The program "Instruments" should open where you can also choose `Zombies`
4. Now you can interact with your app and try to cause the error
5. As soon as the error happens you should get a hint on when your object was released and therefore deallocated.

[image: Zombies]
<sub>(source: [dimzzy.com](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/leaky-zombies-tool.png))</sub>