# iOS ASIFormDataRequest crash

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, asiformdatarequest

I have a signup method that hits an API to sign up a user and return the account information.  Everything works fine, but in my signup viewcontroller, when signup is successful, I pop the signup view.  Once I pop the signup view, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line below.  NOTE - this only happens on the phone.  In the simulator this does not happen.  It seems to be a timing issue somehow, but I cant figure it out.  For example, if I put a breakpointer on [_completionHandlerSignUp release]; then it works every time.

Here is my createAccount method in my DataAccessor class:

```
_completionHandlerSignUp = [handler copy];

the normal request code would be here

[request setCompletionBlock:^
 {
     int statusCode = request.responseStatusCode;

     NSDictionary *json = [request.responseString JSONValue];
     NSString *status = [json valueForKeyPath:@"status"];
     NSLog(@"API JSON %@", request.responseString);

     myAccount.statusCode = statusCode;

     if(statusCode == 200)
     {
         myAccount.status = status;
         myAccount.error = @"";
         myAccount.firstName = firstName;
         myAccount.lastName = lastName;
         Credentials *myCredentials = [[Credentials alloc] init];
         myCredentials.emailAddress = userName;
         myCredentials.passWord = passWord;
         myAccount.credentials = myCredentials;

         [myCredentials release];
     }
     else if(statusCode == 403)
     {
         NSString *error = [json valueForKeyPath:@"error"];
         myAccount.status = status;
         myAccount.error = error;
         NSLog(@"API Error %@",error);
     }

     NSLog(@"TEST - Sending Account Response ");
     _completionHandlerSignUp(myAccount);

     NSLog(@"TEST - DEALLOCATING OBJECTS ");

    [_completionHandlerSignUp release];  <--**EXC_BAD_ACCESS HAPPENS HERE**
    _completionHandlerSignUp = nil;

     }];
```

**And here is the viewcontroller method:**

```
DataAccessor *dataAccessor = [[DataAccessor alloc] init];

        [dataAccessor createAccount:[Utilities getDeviceUDID] user:txtEmail.text password:txtPassword.text firstname:txtFirstName.text lastname:txtLastName.text  completion:^(Account *myAccount)
        {
            [dataAccessor release]; 

            if(myAccount != NULL)
            {
                NSLog(@"Status: %@", myAccount.status);
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", myAccount.error);

                if(myAccount.statusCode == 200)  //handle successful transaction
                {

                    [Preferences signInUser:myAccount.credentials.emailAddress password:myAccount.credentials.passWord];

                    [self popViewController];  **<<<<If I remove this, THERE IS NO CRASH******
                }
                else if(myAccount.statusCode == 403)
                {
                    //todo - handle error
                }
            }


            [self finalUpdate];
        }];

- (void) popViewController
{
    NSLog(@"TEST - Popping View Controller ");

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
    //  MainSelectionMenu *myViewController = [[MainSelectionMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainSelectionMenu" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Something else that is very odd is that my SIGN IN functionality works almost exactly the same way.  Sign in calls the SignIN API in the DataAccessor and when it returns in the view controller, it pops the view.  However, the SIGN IN functionality works fine and NEVER crashes.

EDIT -  Zombies Log:

```
-   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Malloc  1   00:16.125.952   1024    Saveology   +[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:]
1   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Autorelease   00:16.126.025   0   Saveology   +[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:]
2   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Autorelease   00:16.126.026   0   Saveology   -[SaveologyDealsDataAccessor createDealsAccount:user:password:firstname:lastname:divisionid:completion:]
3   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  2   00:16.126.179   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
4   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.126.196   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
5   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.126.266   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
6   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 1   00:16.126.267   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
7   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  2   00:16.127.268   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
8   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.127.302   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
9   0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.127.332   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
10  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.128.711   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
11  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.128.771   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
12  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.129.880   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
13  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  4   00:16.129.889   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
14  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 3   00:16.129.893   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
15  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.129.912   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
16  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.309.250   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
17  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  4   00:16.310.289   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
18  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 3   00:16.310.396   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
19  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.310.640   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
20  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.310.775   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
21  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  4   00:16.310.776   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
22  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 3   00:16.310.789   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
23  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.310.807   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
24  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  3   00:16.311.443   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
25  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  4   00:16.311.469   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
26  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  5   00:16.311.491   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
27  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Retain  6   00:16.311.496   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
28  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 5   00:16.311.501   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
29  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 4   00:16.311.546   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
30  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 3   00:16.311.557   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
31  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 2   00:16.311.563   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
32  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 1   00:16.313.736   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
33  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Release 0   00:16.320.573   0   Foundation  NSRecordAllocationEvent
34  0x11035a00  ASIFormDataRequest  Zombie  -1  00:16.320.964   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I was able to get it to crash in the Simulator ONCE with zombies enabled and the culprit is ASIFormDataRequest GraphicsServices but really no other info :/

Comment: Could you post the full error message you receive with zombies enabled?

Comment: added it, sorry about the format, but not sure how else to display it in SO

Comment: figured it out, dumb simple mistake as usual :)

Comment: BTW - if you are using iOS 5, using ARC saves many a headache.  You will have to add compiler flags for some of the ASIHttpRequest classes, but it is so worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on Zombie Objects to get some more detail about that EXE_BAD_ACCESS error.  Should tell you something about the object that it's expecting to be there. This usually means you've dealloc'd the object pointer too early in the execution of the code.

Turning on Zombies: [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

What happens when you remove this [_completionHandlerSignUp release] line?

Comment: I did get Zombies to run, look above.  Also, when I remove that line it acts no different.