# KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS on EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

How do I trace the crash ?
Iam not able o find where the crash occuring.
while running in iphone I cannot point out the crash.
Looking at this and means nothing to me. I don't see where the error is. I know it crashed on thread 0, but which line?

```
Incident Identifier: 555C82A2-EDBB-42C0-A07C-9A56ECCEB6E6
CrashReporter Key:   041610a7eefb2be334ab0960bdd703499d97e8f5
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         dsd[2282]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/FE16C539-B585-4F05-ABDC-2F745A3F186F/dsd.app/dsd
Identifier:      dsd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-20 17:04:00.836 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x73206776
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37cf8fbc 0x37cf5000 + 16316
1   dsd                             0x000024bc 0x1000 + 5308
2   dyld                            0x2fef4ecc 0x2fee8000 + 52940
3   dyld                            0x2fef4bd2 0x2fee8000 + 52178
4   dyld                            0x2fef27ce 0x2fee8000 + 42958
5   dyld                            0x2fef378e 0x2fee8000 + 46990
6   dyld                            0x2feeaa1a 0x2fee8000 + 10778
7   dyld                            0x2feeeb7e 0x2fee8000 + 27518
8   dyld                            0x2fee92c8 0x2fee8000 + 4808
9   dyld                            0x2fee9058 0x2fee8000 + 4184

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x000bef94    r1: 0x68095820      r2: 0x2fdffd78      r3: 0x2fdffd9c
    r4: 0x7320676e    r5: 0x2ff0cb00      r6: 0x68095820      r7: 0x2fdfeec8
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x1a025608     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x0000249d
    ip: 0x37cf8fad    sp: 0x2fdfeea8      lr: 0x000024c3      pc: 0x37cf8fbc
  cpsr: 0x20000030

    Binary Images:
            0x1000 -    0xcafff +dsd armv7  <7fd71c5abe385b2812aea4313ce90cf3> /var/mobile/Applications/FE16C539-B585-4F05-ABDC-2F745A3F186F/dsd.app/dsd

        0x2fee8000 - 0x2ff09fff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld

        0x300e7000 - 0x300e7fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib

        0x30103000 - 0x30148fff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices

        0x30191000 - 0x301a6fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <2e35ec83cc823bbebf107dc4867e61d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib

        0x301aa000 - 0x301b9fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage

        0x30378000 - 0x3037bfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <48fe217ed667308bb9413c11f5b5b31d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib

        0x3037f000 - 0x3053bfff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO

        0x3053c000 - 0x30616fff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage

        0x3074c000 - 0x307f8fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender

        0x30927000 - 0x30a6cfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <649b7b4a430a340b8c2b85c6fb4e1369> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics

        0x30a74000 - 0x30a74fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib

        0x30a79000 - 0x30a9cfff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom

        0x30aa0000 - 0x30bb7fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a2dbc131fdc0364e822339ca2926b6e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation

        0x30c00000 - 0x30c01fff  DataMigration armv7  <4179a9f217a8300d93c14b6fd87e5c31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration

        0x30c02000 - 0x30c4bfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

        0x30c4c000 - 0x30c4dfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <77460820431837d68f19c81d53b6ca83> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib

        0x30c4e000 - 0x30cc7fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader

        0x31326000 - 0x3133cfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <ff80b6648c24360583e5e624efda4815> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices

        0x31507000 - 0x31527fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib

        0x31528000 - 0x31547fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <17803796ac1d31bdab85e651a74d5e0d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

        0x31661000 - 0x31666fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <ae0aa5856c093beaa792b34cafaa55df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport

        0x3176a000 - 0x31770fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <19d7596821403d998017f03678d40514> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib

        0x31771000 - 0x31782fff  AirTraffic armv7  <8b284911a8e13f30888a1285ce1bc769> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic

        0x31783000 - 0x317a6fff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit

        0x317f0000 - 0x317f7fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib

        0x318b0000 - 0x3196bfff  AVFoundation armv7  <c971a925b82934f8881283aabb2992f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation

        0x31b35000 - 0x31b3bfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <18472eec0dfa3aa993f4ae7f34ec5c52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag

        0x31dab000 - 0x31dacfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib

        0x31dea000 - 0x31e27fff  IOKit armv7  <284ee3241c4a3b43b81b9ff514997013> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit

        0x31e2d000 - 0x31e43fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <ac287acb68d032118cd824a51011638d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib

        0x31eab000 - 0x31ef4fff  CoreMedia armv7  <16e247e3f4a43fc5a72695092cf8ba96> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia

        0x31f68000 - 0x321c2fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <f1f929e78e753147bb4a638e95d29669> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox

        0x32206000 - 0x322f6fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c77ceeffd75e3bcc9df3bbe91e2dac98> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore

        0x323c8000 - 0x3244bfff  CoreMotion armv7  <5e0f8a464b0736cfaa6cf3a0c1f33f2c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion

        0x3244f000 - 0x3253dfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <0f52661fd7af3a448b95f8d93d20f3f7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

        0x32576000 - 0x3258cfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <86ed1499ae1e3f5ba389e657f6a23ced> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib

        0x3266c000 - 0x326b5fff  AddressBook armv7  <9ac3368232663b5786382e33c3773678> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook

        0x326b6000 - 0x326b6fff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib

        0x326b7000 - 0x326bcfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <11ce894432a73b9485cce6f5b1ea6488> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib

        0x327a1000 - 0x327a1fff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate

        0x328ad000 - 0x328f0fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib

        0x3290d000 - 0x3297dfff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage

        0x32a22000 - 0x32a25fff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime

        0x32a4c000 - 0x32a50fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib

        0x32a51000 - 0x32a67fff  EAP8021X armv7  <3f7bd850face343495b2c542ef63d44d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X

        0x32a68000 - 0x32ae7fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cdd807e0d8523476b666a9dc63750bb7> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

        0x32af0000 - 0x32f89fff  UIKit armv7  <87348d5d0d043aa095840765b6d73999> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

        0x32f8a000 - 0x32f8efff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary

        0x3323d000 - 0x33249fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib

        0x3324e000 - 0x3324efff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib

        0x3327d000 - 0x332d4fff  CoreAudio armv7  <d0d388a7373036a08561809242f5a5f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio

        0x332e4000 - 0x332f0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo

        0x33405000 - 0x334d5fff  WebKit armv7  <b79a797a66723db89d6c2f89c0925cf8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit

        0x334eb000 - 0x334effff  libcache.dylib armv7  <607095842baf3c41be3127ed773582ea> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib

        0x334f8000 - 0x336d5fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <59dd50551a893636b94bf4505a62ef97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox

        0x336d6000 - 0x336d6fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib

        0x336d7000 - 0x336d9fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib

        0x336da000 - 0x336e5fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <08bfaa5766853884a09cd70f5ae37017> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices

        0x33762000 - 0x3379cfff  iTunesStore armv7  <689b69ce054439e5ac0cfec52c27679c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore

        0x33ac0000 - 0x33b6dfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib

        0x33b88000 - 0x33b8efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <4e3671438f71326bbc507cb197a31322> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib

        0x33f30000 - 0x34474fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight

        0x34828000 - 0x34ae9fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib

        0x34aea000 - 0x34b45fff  StoreServices armv7  <01e6b5e7449d39b8bc11e39fc217e645> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices

        0x34d7b000 - 0x34d8afff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <083fb830455f3cd0869bf54bfd91108c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices

        0x34d8b000 - 0x34dd6fff  CoreLocation armv7  <77f81f93c6483079b547b3552b0247d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation

        0x3516d000 - 0x3517efff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <637167f4fa5c3cee99418295843e1580> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

        0x3517f000 - 0x35229fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib

        0x3524b000 - 0x35255fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib

        0x35260000 - 0x35266fff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons

        0x35267000 - 0x35271fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib

        0x35272000 - 0x35279fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <f6d1bb9e4b60392f834d4e0ee35105cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices

        0x35354000 - 0x35379fff  OpenCL armv7  <051a834ba5583f47876f0c8b9a1e3dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL

        0x3539d000 - 0x35466fff  Celestial armv7  <f704f5baa8e932289bebd666acecebfa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial

        0x354b4000 - 0x354c8fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <47b0ba3bcfd230a192119445de86cef1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection

        0x35593000 - 0x3559afff  MediaRemote armv7  <dfe4a618896c3402a38f352f3d1d8f5e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote

        0x35695000 - 0x356cefff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox

        0x356cf000 - 0x356d3fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface

        0x356d4000 - 0x356d9fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <49003f67c59730c9ac9c499517a3bb8b> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib

        0x356e5000 - 0x3571afff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <68dbad71a3cc32e5941ad70820f88caa> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration

        0x3571b000 - 0x35727fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <8e4095644cc33c97aa5f9f0620387f88> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib

        0x35751000 - 0x35822fff  HomeSharing armv7  <c4e8aabb89c33e0187fefb71828e2c57> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing

        0x35823000 - 0x35824fff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface

        0x3583e000 - 0x35842fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer

        0x35849000 - 0x3589afff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText

        0x359f8000 - 0x35a00fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi

        0x35ad9000 - 0x35c95fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <b39c3a33756a37ec965230716c612e33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary

        0x35cfa000 - 0x35d07fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib

        0x35d33000 - 0x35d35fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4c0648df13af341e88ddca80be687794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation

        0x35d4f000 - 0x35d50fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

        0x35d74000 - 0x35d75fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <1dadb6191d1835e5b078594218ce14f3> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib

        0x35d93000 - 0x35e6afff  CFNetwork armv7  <794a80e086d23041bfdec139b01e80a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork

        0x35eb4000 - 0x35eb5fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib

        0x35f50000 - 0x36101fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <cbe01e9bfb593b3190c0122297e13f9f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer

        0x36102000 - 0x3624bfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib

        0x362e7000 - 0x36374fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <2eb267ac3b5e32b0a43a61ccb98e6dd1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib

        0x3647e000 - 0x36485fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <00599097fff03d02896974966dee6dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer

        0x36552000 - 0x36592fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib

        0x365a1000 - 0x365a5fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib

        0x36624000 - 0x3666efff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib

        0x3667d000 - 0x36688fff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings

        0x36689000 - 0x3669afff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <2306f236fe113baba3934f1884d36a47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress

        0x366c1000 - 0x36705fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <e05a113469ed345f98f306965abb30dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices

        0x36706000 - 0x36757fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

        0x36911000 - 0x3692efff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <8e5dd82833293382a08f11517e9dcb9b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib

        0x369ab000 - 0x369b1fff  IAP armv7  <f6a99995c7de3db8a52e9a35aac063bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP

        0x369d0000 - 0x369d0fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib

        0x369f2000 - 0x36a3bfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <80836b34a3ef389d82f0fa55cadccc61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration

        0x36a3e000 - 0x36a75fff  Security armv7  <195ed72ea7583470958d72652bd84f03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security

        0x36b6e000 - 0x36b74fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <8d5c3270e68e3dbbb2a72efd71314bf6> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib

        0x36c8a000 - 0x36c8dfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib

        0x36cae000 - 0x36cb1fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <d7f346d1c62d35b18fec919efc67eb84> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib

        0x36e11000 - 0x36e4dfff  AppSupport armv7  <202262953e2d343cbf489fe1e308dba4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport

        0x36e92000 - 0x36edcfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <7cb3680db3bb36a0b59b6d8e8cecf374> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony

        0x36edd000 - 0x36ee6fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf524f1f6e8237369795867c7e2b4e67> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib

        0x36f15000 - 0x37039fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <322e347adc08308ca55fc7de9598248c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore

        0x3729b000 - 0x37a52fff  WebCore armv7  <5a60e1e3f68331e5b426dd4dfeb3def8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore

        0x37b5b000 - 0x37cd9fff  Foundation armv7  <c1afe35de1f63b0db5b7ced0dec7163f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

        0x37cda000 - 0x37cf0fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib

        0x37cf1000 - 0x37cf4fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork

        0x37cf5000 - 0x37dbbfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <d503b4ad04313023bbe76ededd30ed70> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

        0x37dbc000 - 0x37dcbfff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about memory management , an object is pointing to an invalid memory space. Try to use NSZombieEnabled to find line you get this crash ,  here you can find  [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to symbolize the log,  aka drag it into organizer and the crash log will show the function names called.