# Zombie in mixed ARC code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

I am using a non-ARC framework in my ARC-enabled app. Now I get a weird `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at a line that looks like this:

```
return [super prepareURLRequest];  << Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
```

First of all, how is this possible, since `super` is not an object that could possibly have been deallocated. **Update**: Although the Debugger got stuck at this line, it turned out that the problem was one level deeper in the mentioned method.

When I run the thing in [Zombie mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/8863063#8863063) I get the following "zombie stack":

```
Event Type    RefCt     Responsible Caller
Malloc            1     -[MyViewController loadData:]
Retain            2     -[MyDataManager initWithBaseURL:]
Release           1     -[MyDataManager initWithBaseURL:]
Release           0     -[MyViewController loadData:]
Zombie           -1     -[RKRequest prepareURLReuqest]
```

It seems that there is a problem with the url but in ARC I have no means of retaining the URL so that it does not get allocated. So how could I fix this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "super is not an actual object"?

Comment: Well is super an object? Doesn't it represent the super class (but it is not actually instantiated), or am I wrong.

Comment: You are wrong; why do you think that?

Comment: super is the same object as self.  The difference is the way in which the message is sent (`obj_msgSendSuper` instead of `obj_msgSend`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. The problem was that `MyDataManager` was deallocated after the `loadData:` method was through.

So I added a `myDataManager` property to `MyViewController` and the problem disappeared.