# Xcode Instruments can't detect retain cycle for strong delegate type?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, retain-cycle

I just spent an hour trying to fix a retain cycle in my code. It was basically the view controller not getting deallocated after dismiss.

However, when I was using Instruments to check for memory leak, it passed every leak check. Please see the image below.

[image: Instrument Leak Checks]

The problem was when I declared the class protocol, I forgot to mark the delegate as weak...But how come Instruments failed to notice this retain cycle?

I'm quite new to Memory management, if my question is dumb, please understand. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, a strong reference cycle (often) won't be detected by leaks tool. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992338/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-when-leaks-instrument-does-not-show-them/30993476#30993476 for other techniques for finding these sorts of issues.

Comment: @Rob great answer! Thanks! And sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments detect leaks in fairly simple way - if there are no references leading to the root components (say Application Delegate) from an instance, it means that the instance and all instances retaining it are a memory leak, just like Garbage Collector. So if, say, your parent ViewController merely retains another ViewController (which should have been released getting back), and the parent ViewController is still retained itself by any class that is in chain of references to the root components, it is not considered leak.

Comment: how do you know that how profiling works ? do you have a reference/doc ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD, these conclusions are based on my own empirical experience, feel free to correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev is correct, as allocated memory with no reference is the definition of a memory leak. To find retain cycles, you need to look at the "All Heap & Anonymous VM" portion of Instruments. The visual memory debugging may also help.