# Will it cause memory leak with in a swift class method

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, swift3

My problem is I'm not sure if a closure inside a class method can leads to memory leak.
Here is my code

```
class func SomeDownloadFun (pdfDirectory:String) {   

      let destination : DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = {
            _, response in

//----------HERE I Reference the item 'pdfDirectory'-----Will this cause leak?
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfDirectory)

            return (fileURL,[.removePreviousFile,.createIntermediateDirectories])
        }


        let downLoadRequest = Alamofire.download(urlStr!, to: destination)

 downLoadRequest.responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:

//----------HERE I Reference the item 'pdfDirectory'-----Will this cause leak?

                    print("pdfDirectory")


                    break

                case .failure:
                    print("down err")
                    break

                }

            })
```

}

Aa I have comment  out where i think it will cause a leak ,can anybody tell me ,Thanks!

Comment: Well , thanks, but if define my pdfDirectory as NSDictionary or something else  will it cause reference cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Just because you reference an object in a closure doesn’t mean you have a strong reference cycle. You need circular references (e.g. A has strong reference to B and B has its own strong reference back to A), in order to have strong reference cycle, which doesn’t happen here.
2. The `pdfDirectory` isn’t even a reference type (`String` is a `struct`, a value type), so there can’t be a strong reference cycle, anyway. It’s only going to happen with reference types (e.g. `class` rather than `struct`).

Even when you introduced `NSDictionary` into the conversation (a reference type), that alone is not sufficient for there to be a strong reference cycle. Don't jump to conclusions about strong reference cycles on the basis of the existence of closure with some reference type. Figure out (or use ["Debug memory graph"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993476/1271826) or Instruments) what objects to which a given object has strong references, and see determine if there are strong reference cycle at that point.