# IBOutlets are nil in IBAction

Tags: swift, uikit

All the `IBOutles` are initialized properly and have values, but when I press a button in my navigation bar all my `IBOutlets` are `nil` inside that `IBAction`. Setting a `didSet` didn't help, so I couldn't figure out when the values become `nil` as well as cleaning the project.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what error display

Comment: @Jaydip unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: `IBAction` itself won't nil out `IBOutlets`. I don't see any problems with above codes. Check if your `doneButton` is wired with some behavior in your storyboard.

Comment: Are those two screen snapshots a result of one debugging session? I ask because if you notice, `self` refers to two different `FacebookRegistrationVC` instances. I wondering if you accidentally have an incurrence of `FacebookRegistrationVC()` somewhere in your code which, rather than referring to the storyboard-instantiated VC, is creating a second instance not linked to any storyboard scene. You can confirm this by hitting the "Debug memory graph" button (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993476/1271826) and see how many `FacebookRegistrationVC` instances you see in the list on the left.

Answer (score 0):

First this is textFied right, then you can didset textfield text not print because print value in console, it's not set In your textField bro.

so, you can write like

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: AuthenticationTextField!{
        didSet{
            emailTextField.text = "changed"
        }
    }
```