# How to resolve memory cycle in Swift 4 URLSession.downloadTask?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have a basic `viewController` with a single button that when tapped, calls a method to start downloading an image from a given valid url.

I was very careful of passing any strong pointers to the viewcontroller. And I am able to dismiss the viewcontroller away and go back to the presenting controller without any issues.  However, objects instances of `Web()` that are created by the viewcontroller, are not deallocated, even if the viewcontroller's `deinit` is called.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW: the file download is started, progress is reported and file location is reported as well. However, the object is never deallocated once the file is finished downloading.

## viewController.swift

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   //first create an instance of Web class (download helper)
   let web = Web(url: "https://www.google.com.sa/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png")

   // all call back closures have no reference to self    
   web.downloadFile(
       finishedHandler: {fileLocation in print("file stored to \(fileLocation)")},
       progressHandler: {bytes,total in print("written \(bytes) out of \(total)")},
       errorHandler: {msg in print("error: \(msg)")}
  )

}
```

And I have defined `Web()` as `NSObject` which conforms to `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` to take advantage of delegate event methods (`didFinishDownload` / `didWriteBytes`, etc).

## Web.swift

```
import UIKit

class Web : NSObject {
    var urlToDownload : String?

   // the following variables are references to closures passed to the object.
    var progressCallback : ((_ bytesWritten:Int64, _ totalExpectedBytes: Int64)->())?
    var finishedCallback : ((_ fileLocation: String)->())?


    static var instanceCount = 0 // keep track of number of instances created

    init(url: String) {

       Web.instanceCount += 1
       urlToDownload = url
       print(" new instance of Web created. Total : \(Web.instanceCount)")
   }

   deinit {
      Web.instanceCount -= 1
      print("Web instance deallocated. Remaining: \(Web.instanceCount)")

   }
}
```

and I added the file download logic as extension to the same file:

```
extension Web : URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func downloadFile(
        finishedHandler: @escaping (_ fileLocation:String)->(),
        progressHandler: @escaping (_ bytesWritten:Int64, _ totalBytes: Int64)->(),
        errorHandler: @escaping (_ errorMsg:String)->()) {

        // we need to capture the closure because, these will
        // be called once the delegate methods are triggered
        self.progressCallback = progressHandler
        self.finishedCallback = finishedHandler


        if let url = URL(string: self.urlToDownload!) {
             let session = URLSession(
                configuration: .default,
                delegate: self,
                delegateQueue: nil)

            let task = session.downloadTask(with: url)

            task.resume()

        }

    }

    // MARK :- Delegate methods
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        // call the closure if it still exists
        self.finishedCallback?(location.absoluteString)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        // report progress by calling captured closure, if exists
        self.progressCallback?(totalBytesWritten,totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After I traced the issue (using the *Memory Graph Debugger*), I figured it out that the reason of the issue in this chunk of code (Web class - download file method):

```
if let url = URL(string: self.urlToDownload!) {
     let session = URLSession(
        configuration: .default,
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: url)

    task.resume()
}
```

Actually there is an issue related to instantiation `URLSession` without getting rid of it; Therefore, you have to do a -kind of- manual handling to solve it, calling [`finishTasksAndInvalidate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407428-finishtasksandinvalidate) would be appropriate for such an issue:

```
if let url = URL(string: self.urlToDownload!) {
    let session = URLSession(
        configuration: .default,
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: url)

    task.resume()
    // here we go:
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

To make sure it works as expected, I would suggest to add breakpoints to the delegate methods and the `deinit` in the Web class, you should see it works as expected (the delegate method would work and then the `deinit` would be called).

---

**Furthermore:**

If you would like to know more about how to work with the Memory Graph Debugger, you could check: [How to debug memory leaks when Leaks instrument does not show them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992338/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-when-leaks-instrument-does-not-show-them/)

Comment: I spent 2 days trying to find the cause of this issue. I knew the root cause had to do with URLSession, but I never expected the solution is to call finishTaskAndInvalidate

Comment: @dwonvoter it is inappropriate to downvote without mentioning what's the reason if it :)

Comment: Yep, my view controller Leaks if finishTasksAndInvalidate is not called on the URLSession.  Setting the session to Nil does not help.  Only calling finishTasksAndInvalidate() makes it let go of my controller.   The delegate reference is STRONG inside URLSession, which is a no-no.  Not sure why they made the delegate strong there.

Comment: Delegates are free to be strong references as long as there is a mechanism to break the cycle. It's unusual, but not forbidden. URLSessions retain their delegate because you generally want the delegate to exist until the operation completes, at which point the delegate is released and the all the objects are deallocated. This kind of retain loop allows you to kick off network operations and letting them complete on their own without them vanishing in the middle. This is the same pattern GCD uses where blocks retain their queue until they complete.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a URLSession *retains its delegate*, so storing a strong reference to the URLSession in the same object that acts as its `delegate` is circular.

As you've been told, you can break the strong reference by *invalidating* the URLSession. But in general the simple solution is: don't create the circularity in the first place.

Comment: How can i not create the circularity and at the same time be able to monitor download progress?

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader

Answer (score 2):

The problem you can clearly see when debugging using the **Memory Graph Debugger** is that the object `Web` is being held by the `URLSession` object which holds the `CFXURLCache` which in turn holds the `URLSession` back. They have strong references to each other. So only when the session or cache gets freed from memory, the `Web` object will be freed up from memory.

[image: Memory Leak]

---

The **SOLUTION** is simple, you need to invalidate the session to break the cyclic reference between `NSURLSession` and `CFXURLCache` when your download finishes:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    // call the closure if it still exists
    self.finishedCallback?(location.absoluteString)
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```