# How to prevent memory leak with using self in closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have class for download files:

```
class FileDownloader {

    private let downloadsSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    private var task: URLSessionDownloadTask?
    private let url: URL

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    public func startDownload(){
        download()
    }

    private func download(){

        task = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: url) {[weak self] (location, response, error) in
            guard let weakSelf = self else {
                assertionFailure("self was deallocated")
                return }
            weakSelf.saveDownload(sourceUrl: weakSelf.url, location: location, response: response, error: error)
        }

        task!.resume()
    }

    private func saveDownload(sourceUrl : URL, location : URL?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            assertionFailure("error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            return }

        let destinationURL = localFilePath(for: sourceUrl)

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        try? fileManager.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: location!, to: destinationURL)
            print("save was completed at \(destinationURL) from \(String(describing: location))")
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not copy file to disk: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func localFilePath(for url: URL) -> URL {
        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        return documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    }
}
```

When i call `startDownload()` i get an error at debugging at line:

```
assertionFailure("self was deallocated")
```

When i change download function to this:

```
private func download(){

        task = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: url) {(location, response, error) in
            self.saveDownload(sourceUrl: self.url, location: location, response: response, error: error)
        }

        task!.resume()
    }
```

All work nice, but i'm afraid it may cause problems with object that is not properly released in memory. How to avoid such situation? Am i doing things right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, why are you getting that assertion failure? Because you’re letting `FileDownloader` instance fall out of scope. You haven’t shared how you’re invoking this, but you’re likely using it as a local variable. If you fix that, your problem goes away.

Second, when you changed your implementation to remove the `[weak self]` pattern, you don’t have a strong reference cycle, but rather you’ve just instructed it to not release the `FileDownloader` until the download is done. If that’s the behavior you want, then that’s fine. It’s a perfectly acceptable pattern to say “have this keep a reference to itself until the asynchronous task is done.” In fact, that’s precisely what `URLSessionTask` does. Clearly, you need to be absolutely clear regarding the implications of omitting the `[weak self]` pattern, as in some cases it can introduce a strong reference cycle, but not in this case.

---

Strong reference cycles only occur when you have two objects with persistent strong references to each other (or sometimes more than two objects can be involved). In the case of `URLSession`, when the download is done, Apple prudently wrote `downloadTask` method so that it explicitly releases the closure after calling it, resolving any potential strong reference cycle.

For example, consider this example:

```
class Foo {
    func performAfterFiveSeconds(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.doSomething()

            block()
        }
    }

    func doSomething() { ... }
}
```

The above is fine because `asyncAfter` releases the closure when it’s run. But consider this example where we save the closure in our own ivar:

```
class BarBad {
    private var handler: (() -> Void)?

    func performAfterFiveSeconds(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        handler = block

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.calledWhenDone()
        }
    }

    func calledWhenDone() {
        // do some stuff

        doSomething()

        // when done, call handler

        handler?()
    }

    func doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Now this is a potential problem, because this time we save the closure in an ivar, creating a strong reference to the closure, and introducing risk of a classic strong reference cycle.

But fortunately this is easily remedied:

```
class BarGood {
    private var handler: (() -> Void)?

    func performAfterFiveSeconds(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        handler = block

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.calledWhenDone()
        }
    }

    func calledWhenDone() {
        // do some stuff

        doSomething()

        // when done, call handler

        handler?()

        // make sure to release handler when done with it to prevent strong reference cycle

        handler = nil
    }

    func doSomething() { ... }
}
```

This resolves the strong reference cycle when it sets `handler` to `nil`. This is effectively what `URLSession` (and GCD methods like `async` or `asyncAfter`) do. They save the closure until they call it, and then they release it.

Comment: for example i used it in unit testing like that:  func testDownload() {
        
        let downloader = FileDownloader(url: URL(string: URLS.firstFileUrl.rawValue)!)
        downloader.startDownload()
        
        waitForExpectations(timeout: largeTimeout, handler: nil)
    }

Comment: in which case it does make strong reference retain cycle i should be worry about?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban - You need to worry about strong reference cycles when you have objects that have persistent keep strong references to each other. In this case, `downloadTask` releases the closure after calling it, resolving any cycle. Where you need to worry about it is where we know it won’t get released (e.g. a repeating timer that never stops; we have our own closure ivar and neglect to set it to `nil` when we’re done with it; we have strong delegate reference; etc.).

Comment: If you have concerns about strong reference cycles, you can run your actual app, exercise it, return to quiescent state where the relevant objects should be released, and click on the “debug memory graph” button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992338/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-when-leaks-instrument-does-not-show-them/30993476#30993476

Comment: By the way, here are some unrelated observations on your code snippet: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/fd52d2dcc4cdbb8632d1bf59f598a342

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use this:

```
task = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: url) {(location, response, error) in
            self.saveDownload(sourceUrl: self.url, location: location, response: response, error: error)
        }
```

move it to delegates of URLSessionDownloadTask and URLSession

```
class FileDownloader:URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate
```

and implement its methods:

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        debugPrint("Download finished: \(location)")
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        debugPrint("Task completed: \(task), error: \(error)")
    }
```

I know that this value won't be nil but try to avoid forcing unwrapping:

```
task!.resume()
```

> Download tasks directly write the server’s response data to a
>   temporary file, providing your app with progress updates as data
>   arrives from the server. When you use download tasks in background
>   sessions, these downloads continue even when your app is suspended or
>   is otherwise not running.
>
> You can pause (cancel) download tasks and resume them later (assuming
>   the server supports doing so). You can also resume downloads that
>   failed because of network connectivity problems.