# Should I use `weak self` when making asynchronous network request?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

Here is my method to fetch some data from the network:

```
func fetchProducts(parameters: [String: Any],
                success: @escaping ([Product]) -> Void)
```

As you noticed, it has escaping closure. Here is how I call above method in ViewModel:

```
service.fetchProducts(parameters: params, success: { response in
        self.isLoading?(false)
        /// doing something with response
})
```

The question is should I capture `self` weakly or strongly? Why? I think I can capture it strongly. Because, `fetchProducts` is a function which has closure as a parameter. But, I might be wrong. But, from other perspective, I think it should be weak. Because, ViewModel has strong reference to `service`, `service` has strong reference to `success` closure which has strong reference to `self` (which is ViewModel). It creates retain cycle. But `deinit` of ViewModel is called anyway, after `ViewController` which owns ViewModel is deinitialized. It means that there was no retain cycle. Why?

Answer (score 2):

As long as your viewmodel is a class, you have to capture self weakly, otherwise you'll have a strong reference cycle. Since `fetchProducts` is asynchronous, its success closure might be executed *after* your viewmodel has already been deallocated - or would have been deallocated if the closure wasn't holding a strong reference to it. The strong reference in the async closure will block the viewmodel from being deallocated.

If you call `service.fetchProducts` in a class AND access `self` inside the async closure, you do need `[weak self]`. If you were to do this in a value type (`struct` or `enum`) OR if you didn't access `self` inside the closure, you don't need `[weak self]` - in a value type, you cannot even do `[weak self]`.

```
service.fetchProducts(parameters: params, success: { [weak self] response in
        self?.isLoading?(false)
        /// doing something with response
})
```

Comment: Yes, ViewModel is reference type. But, how would you explain that deinit of ViewModel is called even there was strong self?

Comment: @neo whether the strong reference cycle will be created or not, depends on when the closure is executed and when all other references to your viewmodel are deallocated. The strong reference cycle will only be closed if the last reference is inside the closure. So for instance if your network request took 10 seconds to come back with a result, but your user already navigated away from the view storing your view model after 5 seconds, there would be a strong reference cycle due to using strong self. You can guard against this with capturing self weakly.

Comment: Ok, but suppose my network request takes 10 seconds. User navigated out from that screen. Of course, my ViewModel cannot be deinitted. But after `success` closure gets executed, it will be deallocated. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @DávidPásztor _So for instance if your network request took 10 seconds.._ this is not totally correct, I have exactly this case and when network is finished and I got response, everything is deallocated successfully.

Comment: @neo, no it won't be deallocated even after the request returned. That's where you are wrong. The memory leak is created because the viewmodel should've been deallocated as soon as all references outside of that closure were deallocated. However, the closure holding a reference to the viewmodel creates a zombie object that won't be deallocated.

Comment: If it is still unclear how closures can create strong reference cycles, I'd suggest reading some external materials, like [How to prevent memory leaks in Swift closures](https://stablekernel.com/article/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-swift-closures/) or [How to prevent memory leak with using self in closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54431490/4667835).

Comment: Ok. I believe you are right, but I cannot check that ViewModel is not deallocated after request returned. Inside my `fetchProducts`, I created delay for 10 seconds using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. Then, I called `fetchProducts` and navigated back to previous ViewController. Of course, ViewModel and a `ViewController` holding it, was not deallocated. But after as soon as `success` closure finished, they were deallocated. Thanks for links by the way!