# Debug one node memory leak in memory graph

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I have noticed these memory leaks when I used Memory Graph:

[image: NSMutableArray memory leaks]

But I cannot manage to debug those memory leaks. The strange thing is that there is only one object in the graph when I open one of the leaks. The object is NSMutableArray.

Should not there be at least two objects pointing at each other? How can I debug this leak?

Comment: Can you give the code for the class which is causing this? Is this also from profiling in instruments?

Comment: @George_E I cannot give you the code, because I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: In instruments, it should show you where the issue is coming from. For some reason your symbols are missing, so you just get the `0x...` memory locations. It should show a class name for example.

Comment: Turn on the “malloc stack” diagnostic, and then you will see the stack trace where this object was allocated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992338/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-when-leaks-instrument-does-not-show-them/30993476#30993476.