# How to get rid of waiting for Completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, closures, nsurlsession

I load content when the user clicks on a button, wait for the download and show the content to the user.
I use `URLSession.shared.dataTask` and return the response as `(completion: @escaping closure (_ data: Data?) -> Void)`

But, if the user wants to leave the controller before the content is loaded, then with `self.navigationController?.popViewController (animated: true)`
this controller remains in memory (`deinit{}` don`t call). As I understand it, this is because the controller is expecting a Completion Handler callback.

What and how should I use so that when user close this view controller, he will be deleted from memory, and not stay there forever (until the user kills the application)?

Comment: Try using weak reference to self which is the viewcontroller here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> As I understand it, this is because the controller is expecting a Completion Handler callback.

If the view controller is not getting deallocated, it is because there is a lingering strong reference to it. In your case it sounds like your closure is keeping that strong reference. To avoid keeping that strong reference, you would use a `[weak self]` capture list in your closure, e.g.

```swift
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in   // note `[weak self]` capture list
    guard let self = self else { return }    // safely unwrap the optional

    ...                                      // the rest of this like before
}
task.resume()
```

---

If you wanted to take this a step further, you would also cancel the task when you leave, e.g.

```swift
private weak var savedTask: URLSessionTask?

deinit {
    savedTask?.cancel()                          // cancel if if it hasn't finished already
}

func foo() {
    ...

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in   // note `[weak self]` capture list
        guard let self = self else { return }    // safely unwrap the optional
    
        ...                                      // the rest of this like before
    }
    task.resume()

    savedTask = task
}
```

This way, if the sole purpose of the network request is to update the UI, we can free up the network resources when the requested data is no longer required.

---

All of this assumes that this is the only lingering strong reference you have (i.e., that you are seeing `deinit` called when the network request finishes). If not, make sure that *all* asynchronous closures are using weak references and that you do not have any strong reference cycles. Common sources of problems would be repeating timers, observers, etc., or traditional strong reference cycles. (You can use the “debug memory graph” feature to figure out where these strong references are, such as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993476/1271826).)