# my app crash but not show error xcode on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i am developing drawing application in ios. i am touchesmoved event continuos execute after some times crashed my application.but,it's not show error message console and shows (gdb) in console and project is running state it's shows by thread is paused.i am not bookmark statement's at any point..!

My state below screen shot

[image]

Comment: No breakpoint's.i am already checking..!

Comment: I am having same issue. Were you able to encounter actual reason?

Comment: @Dimple Panchal your using xcode and mac os version tell me?

Answer (score 3):

Try Enabling `NSZombie`

It May Be `EXE_BAD_EXCESS`.

You can check how to enable zombie  and many more to resolve crash issue in your application from the Following Link

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

   2.https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917557/730776

Regards
Neil

Comment: i am trying not error not display like EXE_BAD_EXCESS not showing thread is paused not show line..!

Comment: than you can add exception break point too.. it will stop at location where it going to crash

Answer (score 1):

Is your app launching (maybe with a black screen) at simulator/device launched? In short whats the device state. In my case it was not able to find the SDK and there was a popup in simulator window, which somehow got hidden and I was clueless for some time.

Comment: My app runs a bit, it crash on setNeedsDisplay, I found this while debugging but I am not able to find its solution?

Comment: If you can post some code of yours, maybe some mem leaks or pre-releasing of objects, just a wild guess for now...