# Problems with load Detailview

Tags: objective-c, detailview

I have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TabellenDetailViewController *detailViewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabellenDetailViewController"];
    Book2 *aBook2 = [books2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController2.tea_names = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aBook2.tea_name];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController2 animated:YES];
}
```

For better understanding I have a Storyboard with:

Navigation Controller -> MasterTableViewController -> DetailMasterTableViewController -> TabelleViewController -> DetailTabelleViewcontroller

It works fine to TabelleViewController and If I pick a cell in TabelleViewController the program stops with that error:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([XMLAppDelegate class])); <--- Here with Thread1:Program received signal: "SIGABRT".
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check the `tea_names` property is retained by the `TabellenDetailViewController` instance
- Add the exceptions breakpoint to see the exact exception location

> Click on the Breakpoints symbol (2nd from the right) in the Navigator
>   pane, click the + button at the bottom of the pane, and select Add
>   Exception Breakpoint. From the bubble that appears, I selected
>   Objective-C from the Exception choice (although I suspect you can
>   safely leave it at all if you desire), and I left the Break selection
>   at On Throw. Once you click Done, you should then have a new
>   exceptions breakpoint in the list. ([read more](http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2011/04/18/xcode-4-exception-breakpoint/))

- Enable zombie-mode to track the memory problems ([Xcode 4 how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4))

Comment: Problem solved!
The Problem was that I changed the prosperities in the wrong Storyboard!
Thx a lot !