# Application Freezing when calling CocoaAsyncMethod scheduleDequeueRead

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using CocoaAsyncSocket library to create a TCP socket connection.  The problem I'm having is after a few library methods are called, I'm getting an error.

appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    socket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![socket connectToHost:@"199.5.83.63" onPort:11005 error:&error]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
    }

    [socket readDataWithTimeout:10 tag:1];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[tekMatrixViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tekMatrixViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And here are my methods from the CocoaAsyncSocket Library:

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    NSData *strData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:strData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"RX length: %d", [data length]);
    if(msg)
    {
        NSLog(@"RX:%@",msg);
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Fail");
    }    
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"error - disconnecting");
    //start reconnecting procedure here...
}

- (void)onSocketDidDisconnect:(AsyncSocket *)sock
{
    NSLog(@"disconnected");
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSLog(@"connected");
}
```

When I run my app in the simulator, this is what my output log spits out:

```
2012-06-08 13:17:30.808 tekMatrix[2793:f803] connected
2012-06-08 13:17:30.815 tekMatrix[2793:f803] RX length: 8
2012-06-08 13:17:30.816 tekMatrix[2793:f803] Fail
```

After that, I get an error in the AsyncSocket.m file (part of library) in this method:

```
- (void)scheduleDequeueRead
{
    if((theFlags & kDequeueReadScheduled) == 0)
    {
        theFlags |= kDequeueReadScheduled;
        [self performSelector:@selector(maybeDequeueRead) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 inModes:theRunLoopModes];
    }
}
```

Specifically, the error is on line:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(maybeDequeueRead) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 inModes:theRunLoopModes];
```

And the exception is:  **Thread 1: BAD_EXC_ACCESS (code 1=0, address=0xd0688b8a)**

After that, the app is completely frozen in the simulator.  If anybody could offer some insight as to why this is causing the app to freeze, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the library I'm using:  [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

***EDIT:***

After Enabling Zombie Objects and running the app in the simulator, this is spit out in the output:

```
2012-06-08 14:53:15.416 tekMatrix[3217:f803] *** -[__NSArrayI count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6d10a70
```

I'll have to do a little digging on this and figure out what's happening.

***EDIT 2:***

After a little digging using instruments, I found out the following:

```
An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x6b8bb10.
```

***EDIT 3:***

Now the error reads:

Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Here is a screenshot from instruments.  I'm not really following how to interpret this, though.  It looks like I'm sending a message to an object that has been deallocated.  Is this true?  If so, how do I go about figuring out where this occurs?

If the image is hard to see, here's a direct link:  [Instruments Screenshot](http://i890.photobucket.com/albums/ac103/mmh924/ScreenShot2012-06-08at31523PM.png)

[image: Instruments Screenshot]

Comment: can you show the code, where you create the AsyncSocket object? along with the property, if it is written to one.

Comment: AsyncObject is at the top of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  I inadvertently left out that line of code when I was weeding through commented out lines.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but if I remove the line "[socket readDataWithTimeout:10 tag:1];" then the app doesn't freeze or generate an error.  It only connects to the host and doesn't read any data.

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  Most of the code I have put together has been collectively put together between tutorials and help from SO users.  Why would I need to use a property socket?

Comment: you know, what a property is?

Comment: My understanding is that properties are used to easily take advantage of an object's accessor methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a object, that doesnt exsits anymore. Probably you are under-retaining/over-releasing it.

see this answer for a tool to find such objects: [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Upvoted since the answer at least allowed the original questioner to refine the question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo my apologies.  I'm still learning the functionality of SO. Up voted :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's way after the fact, but I just had this same exact problem.  The solution was adding the ARC flag to AsyncSocket.m, -fobjc-arc

:)