# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: with xCode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, segmentation-fault, swift2, xcode7

My code is unable to build on xcode 7. What is Segmentation fault?

[image]

Comment: I guess you can find solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10987927/5362916

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault happens when your code tries to access memory that it isn't allowed to access. This is often a sign of an uninitialized reference.

It's not clear to me from your screenshot exactly what is going on, though. Perhaps you could provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like it is happening when you build your project. If this is correct, you need to create a minimal example that displays the problem i.e a code fragment that crashes the compiler in the same way and then you need to raise a bug report about it with Apple (supplying your minimal example so they can reproduce it).

This has happened to me a couple of times in the past and the way I have identified the bit that crashes the compiler is to comment out everything in the source file and then add it back in function by function.That will narrow the problem down to the function. After that you repeat with the lines of code in the offending function, until you get the line that crashes the compiler.

Along the way you may find a work around to stop the compiler crashing. If you do, do not be tempted to skip reporting the bug to Apple. They need to know.

Comment: Right said. I restart xcode, clean and build project. Now it is working. May be it is a glitch in latest code.