# Setting delegate when initializing ViewController in other ViewController

Tags: objective-c

In the *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:* implementation of my UITableViewController subclass I'm using this code snippet:

```
AlarmPicker *alarmPicker = [[AlarmPicker alloc] init];
alarmPicker.scrollViewDelegate = alarmPicker;
[cell.contentView addSubview:alarmPicker.view];
```

*AlarmPicker* implements various *UIScrollViewDelegate* methods.

In *AlarmPicker.h* I'm declaring *scrollViewDelegate* as follows:

```
@property (assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> scrollViewDelegate;
```

This is then being used in the implementation part of *AlarmPicker*:

```
UIScrollView *returnScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
...
returnScrollView.delegate = self.scrollViewDelegate;
```

Unfortunately *scrollViewDelegate* is always null in this *AlarmPicker* instance so the implemented delegate methods don't get called at all.

A workaround would be to put the *UIScrollViewDelegate* method implementations into the class which does the alloc and init:

```
...
alarmPicker.scrollViewDelegate = self;
...
```

But that would be a very bad solution.

What do I have to do in order to tell the *AlarmPicker* instance that it should use itself as its delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason that you can't just write `returnScrollView.delegate = self` in your AlarmPicker class?

I don't see any reason why your scrollViewDelegate member would be nil here, unless the line `returnScrollView.delegate = self.scrollViewDelegate;` is happening in your init method, in which case you could move it to a later method or pass the required delegate in your AlarmPicker's init method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. returnScrollView.delegate = self brings up an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when beginning to drag the UIScrollView. So I thought it would be a better idea to set the delegate from "outside".

Comment: I would suggest turning on [zombies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/8863063) to track down that crash. If you can find the stacktrace for that crash, you could also post a question about that.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse! Turning on zombies really helped to find the cause for this crash: `-[SDAlarmPicker respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance: `-[AlarmPicker respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance`. I think ARC is responsible for that. Now I'm using an instance variable to alloc and init the _AlarmPicker_ instance. Maybe that's not the finest solution, but it's working.

Comment: You're welcome. That sounds like a fine solution to me. If my answer was helpful, you might consider accepting it; that will encourage others to answer your questions in the future.