# can not get clue from zombie about a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, zombie-process, nszombieenabled

I am getting this error from the console

```
[Not A Type _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I also enalbe zombie in `Diagonotics` but can not get any hint what the error is. My xcode is hung and throwing me the message below :

[image]

and zombie shows me nothing just like

[image]

what is the error about and how can i use zombie in a proper way to catch the error..

Comment: Just check your object is over released. And for proper way of testing zombie look at this links 
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: can you see which line it crashed from stack trace?

Comment: @Bhargavi : i did try the tutorial from your reference but zombie gave me nothing

Comment: @xlc : [this](http://cl.ly/NHJe) is what I am getting from xcode

Comment: If zombie is giving you nothing then there may be possibility of trying to access things on main thread from background thread while some process is going on. Are you having such things in your code?