# iPhone segment errors on device & crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, fault

My latest iPhone/iPad application works fine on the simulator.
On the iPad, it works fine for sometime but then crashes. The console shows that it is dues to a segmentation fault that I am assuming is happening due to a message being sent to a zombie. Since this is happening only on the actual device it will not be possible for me to use the NSZombieEnabled/Instruments.

What debug options do I have in the absence of instruments/zombie-detection on actual device?

Code Review  - Completed, did not find anything obvious
Put comments and follow through the narrow down on zombies - In progress

What else can I do? any suggestion will be appreciated.

I did go through the past questions but did not get many options to look at....I apologize in advance if this question is already answered *but* would appreciate if you could share the link or provide guidance.

R.S.

Comment: Can enabling the zombie tracing cause crash of the app on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post to see how to turn on Zombie objects.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917557/613156

You can turn it on through the diagnostics panel and it will run on your device.

Comment: In my understanding zombie tracing is not possible on the device. To double check - I tried the instructions (on IPad not the simulator) and did not get the trace zombie option on the instruments. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use instruments to trace zombies but you can enable NSZombie  Enabled and it will give you a little bit more information to go on than just throwing a BAD_EXEC