# NSThread Showing SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to IOS I need to implement NSThread in my program, but when it invoked it shows an SIGABRT error. my current code is given below

XMLParser.m

```
-(void)loadXML
{
    categories =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *filepath =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cd_catalog" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate =self;
    [parser parse];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    xmlParser =[[XMLParser alloc]init];
    NSThread *myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadXML) object:nil];
    [myThread start];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

please tell me what is wrong with my program

Comment: Are you using ARC and where is your application crashing after `viewDidLoad` of inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yes I'm using ARC and its crashing when it reaches the nsthread implementation

Comment: It can be due to the run loop. Can you start run loop inside `loadXML`?

Comment: how...I dont know how to implement that as I said I'm trying to study this my self

Comment: @AlenJoy You need to provide a lot more detail about the error. Most likely you are getting a message about an invalid selector being called on an object of a certain type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to solve your problem...

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSThread *myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doParsing) object:nil];
    [myThread start];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)doParsing
{
    xmlParser =[[XMLParser alloc]init];
    [xmlParser loadXML];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `NSThread` object you can start a thread using

```
//performSelectorInBackground:withObject: is NSObject's method
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadXML) withObject:nil];
```

I didn't find any buggy code but [enable `NSZombie`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2190227/468724) and seee which object is causing this.

Comment: It needs to be `[xmlParser performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadXML) withObject:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

loadXML is not define on ViewController so your thread code should be changed to use an instance of XMLParser instead of self like so:

```
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:parser selector:@selector(loadXML) object:nil];
[thread start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple introduced GCD, you may solve it without creating any `NSThread` instance.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_object(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  [self loadXML];
});
```