# iPad apllication crashing when entered into foreground from background while doing server request

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ipad, crash

I am having problem when I start a server request and my application enters into foreground from background, It crashes when entered into foreground. I am not able to figure out where it is crashing as it is giving this error message.

```
*** -[WebserviceDataConnection respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f25e9d0
```

> **WebserviceDataConnection** is a class where I am doing server request.

I don't have any background implementation application should store its state when going into background and resume when entered into foreground from previous state.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on NSZombieEnabled: [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

Then look at how you're dealing with the notification that the app is going to the background and deal with shutting the web service down fully. In particular ensure that any delegate relationships that `WebserviceDataConnection` class is participating in are nilled.

Comment: I already enabled NSZombie Object. hence forth it gives me error message.

Comment: Fair enough, you need to concentrate on delegate and observer (NSNotification) pattern interaction that your WebserviceDataConnection class is involved in.

Comment: Yes, Wain There was issue with NSNotification. Thanks