# ios using NSPredicate to filter content crash if the result is null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nspredicate

I have array of dictionaries like this:

```
clients (
        {
        country = canada;
        city = vancouver;
    },
{
        country = Mexico;
        city = Mexico;
    },
{
        country = UK;
        city = London;
    },
{
        country = USA;
        city = NewYork;
    },
}
```

Where if I use NSPredicate to find the clients in USA like this:

```
NSPredicate *usaPredicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@", @"USA"];
self.usa = [listOfClients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:usaPredicte];
```

works just fine but if for some reason the result of the predicte is null for example in this case:

```
NSPredicate *peruPredicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@", @"Peru"];
self.peru = [listOfClients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:peruPredicte];
```

I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdcb6e0
```

Any of you knows why or how can avoid having this error when the predicate is empty or null?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you by any chance reusing the `listOfClients` pointer for something else between the two calls?

Comment: the listofClients is intact between calls

Comment: when a variable changes to a different object that's often a sign that there is a problem with memory management. You should [check for zombies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/4917557#4917557)

Comment: `NSPredicate *usaPredicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country contains %@", @"USA"];
self.usa = [listOfClients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:usaPredicte];` as you are looking for `Country` in Dictionary of Array so use your key which you want to filter. replace your code. Good Luck

Comment: self.peru is a "NSDictionary"?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(country ==  %@)", @"USA"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [listOfClients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Assuming filterArray always have count 1.

```
if (filteredArray.count ) 
     self.usa = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"country"];
```

Comment: Still have the same problem.

Comment: after above line add  if (filteredArray.count ) self.usa = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"country"];