# App is crashing after launch

Tags: ios, xcode, profiler, provisioning-profile

I have Xcode project and under that project I have two targets, two separate apps which core functionality is the same, but they are using different Bundle IDs and different provisioning profiles. In signing certificates only the **app ID prefix** is the same (i.e., my Team ID).
The first application works fine, but now when I'm starting to run a second application using Xcode profiler, application launched and after splash screen image application crashed without any error information, in the other side when I'm running the applications on the test device everything works fine.

What is the problem? I spent whole my day to this issue , but it didn't help :(

My bet is that something is wrong with certificates/provisioning profile, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: run it by enabling `NSZombie`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,
problem was connected with preprocessor macroses, I forgot to define preprocessor macroses for Release configuration.