# Application was crashing without any error message

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports, ipad-3

i am doing one application.That application is running successfully in ipad simulators.But app was crashed in ipad retina simulator without any exception or error message.And the crash report for that crash is

```
Process:         lsd [2796]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd
Identifier:      lsd
Version:         40
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-04-04 11:11:31.214 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000000001fd

VM Regions Near 0x1fd:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000002000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release
iPhone Simulator 463.9.4, iPhone OS 6.0 (iPad Retina/10A403)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0073509b objc_msgSend + 15
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0098841c CFRelease + 108
2   MobileCoreServices              0x003f3fbb _LSServer_CopyVendorIdentifier + 1335
3   MobileCoreServices              0x0040d912 _LSPluginServer_GetVendorIdentifierForAppIdentifier + 311
4   MobileCoreServices              0x004120bb _XGetVendorIdentifierForAppIdentifier + 238
5   MobileCoreServices              0x0041224d LSPlugin_server + 119
6   MobileCoreServices              0x0041e6e8 serverCallback + 154
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00981c93 __CFMachPortPerform + 131
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00981bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00981962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
10  CoreFoundation                  0x009b2bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
11  CoreFoundation                  0x009b1f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
12  CoreFoundation                  0x009bdf91 CFRunLoopRun + 129
13  MobileCoreServices              0x0041e638 _LSServerMain + 360
14  lsd                             0x00001aa6 0x1000 + 2726
15  lsd                             0x00001a41 0x1000 + 2625

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x014d19ca kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x01102c2b _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 863
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x011028cc _dispatch_mgr_thread + 61

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x014d10ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0138e0ac _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0138de79 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x01375d2a start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xbfffe5ac  ebx: 0x009883be  ecx: 0x0073c2c4  edx: 0x000001f5
  edi: 0xbfffe5ac  esi: 0x000001f5  ebp: 0xbfffe448  esp: 0xbfffe3e8
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x0073509b   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x000001fd
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x1ffb +lsd (40) <C84BC72A-C659-312E-9C08-5F1CAB7FC201> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd
    0x5000 -   0x292ffb +Foundation (992) <33D58583-D8E9-3E20-9CC1-13C63C9EC28C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
  0x3e3000 -   0x466ffb +MobileCoreServices (40) <D9ACED0B-062E-390A-822B-F3AF04C26D9F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
  0x4a1000 -   0x4a4ff7 +MobileInstallation (251) <85DC2B13-85EC-31DB-9771-54E80E911562> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
  0x4aa000 -   0x4c6ffd +libSystem.dylib (65.4) <7095EDF3-1274-3A6D-AB48-C941EC0BD00F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
  0x4da000 -   0x691ff1 +libicucore.A.dylib (491.19) <11DCDD9E-2709-3568-A02E-327BE5163C4B> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
  0x71e000 -   0x829f2f +libobjc.A.dylib (532.1.1) <97D87A00-8F28-30CC-B4C0-6E36A69ACDAA> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  0x842000 -   0x93eff7 +libxml2.2.dylib (22.3) <8C34E1FD-F90B-3158-9A97-D5DC923D52DC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  0x96c000 -   0x97bff7 +libz.1.dylib (44) <795F02AA-F065-3D5D-9D06-2A4E4DBC625C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
  0x980000 -   0xb26ffb +CoreFoundation (793) <6B4B4B13-691B-3CFF-93AB-3AFD3097A9E4> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
  0xc3c000 -   0xdacff3 +CFNetwork (609) <47FBDF79-04B5-38F5-842F-0A63AAB06EAC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
  0xe53000 -   0xe9effb +SystemConfiguration (499) <1272155C-A362-3F63-A2C2-45350BDAA2B8> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
  0xec0000 -   0xf09ff3 +Security (1326.6) <2CD7C6B1-7699-3801-9028-4DA115290391> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
  0xf2f000 -   0xf34ffe +IOKit (65.4) <9E3253CE-A35B-3BAA-9492-B47110EDE377> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
  0xf3e000 -   0xf5dffb +libCRFSuite.dylib (32) <D608B97C-51A7-3299-A5F2-77EE57A02750> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
  0xf67000 -   0xf68ffb +liblangid.dylib (114) <E02691B6-2660-327A-85D9-65079160FF3E> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
  0xf6c000 -   0xf7dfff +GenerationalStorage (130) <FBB045C2-877A-32E0-BA98-CA9AE1B8934B> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
  0xf85000 -   0xfe9ff3 +libstdc++.6.dylib (56) <5F8C495C-35F3-3D7B-AC32-27778B7DECE5> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 0x1047000 -  0x105affb +libbsm.0.dylib (28) <2503C190-0D01-3D5B-B85E-D01BCA738FBC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
 0x1062000 -  0x107bfff +SpringBoardServices (2127.8) <64D6B728-7FE7-3051-AFC3-AFA34A2A10F3> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
 0x108e000 -  0x10afff7 +libc++abi.dylib (24.1) <FCBF2B99-631B-396B-870A-38411C972445> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
 0x10d9000 -  0x10d9ffc +libSystem.override.dylib (65.4) <42812ECC-E4E0-3114-A1AA-B179BB4A464C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.override.dylib
 0x10de000 -  0x10e2ffb +libcache_sim.dylib (59) <BB7DBAB8-045E-35F3-9635-2AE93040A434> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcache_sim.dylib
 0x10e7000 -  0x10f1ffb +libcommonCrypto_sim.dylib (60032.1) <1973A2E3-0218-3B23-9C68-8E8D84205AFB> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto_sim.dylib
 0x10fc000 -  0x1114fff +libdispatch.dylib (244.33) <D3AAC264-D870-3488-891A-75B5EF49218F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
 0x1127000 -  0x1130fff +libnotify_sim.dylib (103.10) <517E3E3A-98C5-3A88-B54D-E6CD8A57D2DA> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libnotify_sim.dylib
 0x1137000 -  0x11a9fe7 +libsystem_sim_c.dylib (849.29) <093F885E-F90D-3E33-AAAF-4D3425A9539C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_c.dylib
 0x11ca000 -  0x11cbffb +libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib (60) <E0816229-3EA6-37AD-B22F-70BC70351B6D> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib
 0x11cf000 -  0x11d7fff +libsystem_sim_dnssd.dylib (397.33) <D6A8EA9B-A43F-3A20-AD5A-00E5D65768B0> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_dnssd.dylib
 0x11dd000 -  0x11f0ffb +libsystem_sim_info.dylib (421.3) <FF264FBC-B24E-36C8-BCC7-4D75E5BC2C90> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_info.dylib
 0x11fb000 -  0x122aff3 +libsystem_sim_m.dylib (3029.2) <D6EEB53F-EA1D-3FFE-B0D5-0C42696E8979> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_m.dylib
 0x1231000 -  0x1245ffb +libsystem_sim_network.dylib (130.7) <8E5B53B9-BB8F-36DC-ADA2-8C474365F855> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_network.dylib
 0x1252000 -  0x1273ff7 +libxpc.dylib (173.35) <64B1F71B-74F0-38A0-83B2-5555EBC5F344> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
 0x1286000 -  0x128dffb +libcopyfile_sim.dylib (90.2) <5B4E4523-645A-33C0-BFF8-A90D501CA8C5> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile_sim.dylib
 0x1292000 -  0x1294ff7 +libdyld_sim.dylib (212.3) <C1F660E0-A06C-3A40-9F5B-ED6DAD1FAFDC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdyld_sim.dylib
 0x1299000 -  0x129affb +libremovefile_sim.dylib (24.2) <E5BACEA1-B6C6-336C-8472-9F1CFDAFAF14> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libremovefile_sim.dylib
 0x129f000 -  0x129ffff +libSystem.host.dylib (169.3) <81C58EAB-0E76-3EAB-BDFD-C5A6FE95536F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.host.dylib
 0x12a6000 -  0x12f6fff +libcorecrypto_sim.dylib (121) <1F8AADB6-0A37-30DC-9B88-7FCAE9643A4F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto_sim.dylib
 0x1303000 -  0x1307ffe  libcache.dylib (57) <834FDCA7-FE3B-33CC-A12A-E11E202477EC> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
 0x130c000 -  0x1317fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60027) <8EE30FA5-AA8D-3FA6-AB0F-05DA8B0425D9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
 0x1322000 -  0x1325ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <CE5DBDB4-0124-3E2B-9105-989DF98DD108> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
 0x132c000 -  0x1334fff  libcopyfile.dylib (89) <4963541B-0254-371B-B29A-B6806888949B> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
 0x133a000 -  0x133bfff  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19) <3B523729-84A8-3D0B-B58C-3FC185060E67> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
 0x1340000 -  0x1342fff  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <05D6FF2A-F09B-309D-95F7-7AF10259C707> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
 0x1348000 -  0x1348fff  libkeymgr.dylib (25) <D5E93F7F-9315-3AD6-92C7-941F7B54C490> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
 0x134c000 -  0x1353fff  liblaunch.dylib (442.26.2) <310C99F8-0811-314D-9BB9-D0ED6DFA024B> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
 0x135b000 -  0x135fff7  libmacho.dylib (829) <5280A013-4F74-3F74-BE0C-7F612C49F1DC> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
 0x1364000 -  0x1365fff  libquarantine.dylib (52.1) <094A1501-373E-3397-B632-8F7C5AC8EFD5> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
 0x136a000 -  0x136bfff  libremovefile.dylib (23.2) <9813B2DB-2374-3AA2-99B6-AA2E9897B249> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
 0x1371000 -  0x1371fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (59) <3A743C5D-CFA5-37D8-80A8-B6795A9DB04F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
 0x1375000 -  0x1432feb  libsystem_c.dylib (825.26) <6E35A83F-1A5B-3AF9-8C6D-D7B57B25FB63> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
 0x146e000 -  0x1475fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (379.38.1) <4F164CA8-4A4F-3B27-B88A-0926E2FEB7D4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
 0x147b000 -  0x14a7ff7  libsystem_info.dylib (406.17) <AA5611DB-A944-3072-B6BE-ACAB08689547> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
 0x14bc000 -  0x14d6ffc  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.24.15) <9E58DCC0-D5FF-37E1-AA7F-F2206719E138> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
 0x14e7000 -  0x1514ffe  libsystem_m.dylib (3022.6) <9975D9C3-3B71-38E3-AA21-C5C5F9D9C431> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
 0x151e000 -  0x152cff3  libsystem_network.dylib (77.10) <7FBF5A15-97BA-3721-943E-E77F0C40DBE1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
 0x1538000 -  0x1542fff  libsystem_notify.dylib (98.5) <7EEE9475-18F8-3099-B0ED-23A3E528ABE0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
 0x154b000 -  0x154cfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (220.3) <C532F6A6-7E85-38F3-8660-EC1066DF67BE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
 0x1551000 -  0x1552ffd  libunc.dylib (25) <58599CBF-E262-3CEA-AFE1-35560E0177DC> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
 0x1558000 -  0x155fffb  libunwind.dylib (35.1) <E1E8D8B3-3C78-3AB1-B398-C180DC6DCF05> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
 0x1566000 -  0x15b2fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (106.2) <20EBADBA-D6D6-36F0-AE80-168E9AF13DB6> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
 0x15bf000 -  0x15e2fff +BackBoardServices (2127.8) <FD1EE1DF-543E-3319-981D-CF8359485DF2> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
 0x1601000 -  0x1612ff7 +GraphicsServices (504) <B2DDE38F-AA35-30AB-A0B4-B9282DA105A1> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
 0x1623000 -  0x162cfff +XPCObjects (39) <D4B1170E-442D-35BC-A3B3-E7EAEE0A7A8F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
 0x1636000 -  0x1645ff7 +libMobileGestalt.dylib (154) <1524F86E-1175-310F-AB3C-370E96CBC16E> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
 0x1652000 -  0x1822fff  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 400.17) <8C2744FF-6DB5-344A-BBDB-4F8358150087> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
 0x187b000 -  0x18e3ff7 +IOKit.host (755.24.1) <70DE925B-51E8-3C65-8928-FB49FD823D94> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/umbrella/IOKit.host
 0x190e000 -  0x191affe  libkxld.dylib (2050.24.15) <BEC097B0-9D9A-3484-99DB-0F537E71963E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
 0x191f000 -  0x19e0ff3 +libsqlite3.dylib (142) <279B5524-D0A4-3A85-94F1-0A27DEC83B1D> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 0x19f1000 -  0x19f5ff3 +MobileSystemServices (1) <F5F1E086-F334-3700-A427-E5C0B8F9A789> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
 0x19fb000 -  0x1a33ffb +Bom (189) <43D5F33D-0E1F-32C6-AA13-04DA48A641D2> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
 0x1a42000 -  0x1a4efff +libbz2.1.0.dylib (30) <E1B2BAFE-50A4-3E92-89DE-AEC39AC82CB9> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x8feaf000 - 0x8fee1e57  dyld (210.2.3) <23516BE4-29BE-350C-91C9-F36E7999F0F1> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1156
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 960

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=24.8M resident=23.6M(95%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1224K(5%)
Writable regions: Total=30.4M written=1632K(5%) resident=2828K(9%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=27.7M(91%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
(null) (reserved)                    12K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CoreServices                        352K
MALLOC                             20.2M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
Mach message                          8K
Stack                              64.6M
VM_ALLOCATE                           4K
__DATA                             1444K
__LINKEDIT                         6048K
__PAGEZERO                            4K
__TEXT                             18.9M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                       211.5M
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             323.5M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    323.5M
```

But i am unable to understand this report.Can you please anybody tell me what's the problem.

Comment: try - Reset content and settings on simulator then run it again

Comment: It's working.But due to this reason only my app was rejected by apple.SO what can i do?

Comment: Enable NSZombieEnabled option see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4 and attach a simulated crash log. Google simulated log if you are not aware

Comment: Not showing any error message in console.Where i can attach the crash log.

Comment: Can you please try Zoombie?

Comment: I tried,then also it will snot show any error message in console.

Answer (score 0):

to catch exception where your app is crashing you have to pit exception breakpoint for debugging   like below image

[image: reference image for exception breakpoint]

hope this will help you identify crash point