# Crashed: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority - EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008

Tags: crash, ios7.1

I get this error frequently from my testers on their iPhone 4 - no crash on iPhone 5s, iPad Air, iPad mini, not even on an iPhone 3GS.

I thought it's memory related, but according to instruments I only need up to 14MB during that operation, and Crashlytics shown available RAM of 120 MB - so I guess that's not the problem, right?

What else could be the cause for that crash? It happens during the downloading of files with FTPManager (https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager).

```
3 ... FTPManager.m line 370
    -[FTPManager _downloadFile:toDirectory:fromServer:]

24 ... FTPManager.m line 475
     -[FTPManager downloadFile:toDirectory:fromServer:]
```

Comment: I have the same error with you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651498/ios-com-apple-root-default-overcommit-priority. Did you solve this problem? PLEASE take your time to help me with this issue. Thank you very much

Comment: You can fix it by enabling NSZombieEnabled. Instructions are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651498/ios-com-apple-root-default-overcommit-priority)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is dereferencing a null pointer on a background thread.

Without the stack trace or code, it's impossible to say more.