# checking for nil before sending message

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, null

I am having this issue in Xcode 6. It is fine if I use this in Xcode 5 or below.

Objects are automatically instantiated even though it's `nil` and can't check `nil`.

```
NSString *userID = [DataManager sharedInstance].currentUser.userId;

if (!userID) {
    userID = @"user";
}
[userInfo setObject:userID forKey:LogDataUserIDKey];
```

That's what I am doing and I am getting `EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x443b800c)` at the last line.
`userID` is instantiated as my attached screenshot. How can I check whether `userID` is nil. I am lost. Please advise. [image]

Comment: You do realize that Xcode is just an IDE? This question has nothing whatsoever to do with Xcode.

Comment: have tried to log the userID before setting it in dictionary and after the if statement?

Comment: If I put `NSLog(@"userID : %@", userID);` right after `userID` assignment, I also got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: @dandan78 i am having that issue only in Xcode 6. Not in Xcode 5. That's why I put Xcode 6. Xcode is just an IDE i know. but different version of xcode is different version of compiler, right?

Comment: @MinSoe Ok, then that's important info that should've been included in your question. Always include all relevant information.

Comment: @dandan78 ya? you removed it because you think it's irrelevant.

Comment: @MinSoe You weren't clear. You never said it worked fine in the previous version of Xcode.

Comment: @dandan78 my bad for posting unclear question.

Comment: can you tell me what object is your [DataManager sharedInstance] class method returning as your log says that self is representing the DataManager class. But you say, it is giving you the compile time error when replacing [DataManager sharedInstance] with self?

Comment: @iHulk this is what inside DataManager's sharedInstance `+ (DataManager*)sharedInstance{
 @synchronized(self){
  
  if(!_sharedInstance){
   _sharedInstance = [[self alloc]init];
  }
  return _sharedInstance; 
 }
 
 return nil;
}`

Comment: Have you tried debugging with NSZombies? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4917557/909655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I am able to fix the issue. It is because inside this `User` object which is `[DataManager sharedInstance].currentUser`, `userId` is declared as both instance variable and property.

```
@interface User : NSObject <NSCopying>{
NSString *userId; // instance variable
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userId;
```

So, by removing the instance variable declaration and it fixed the issue.

```
@interface User : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userId;
```

But, I am not sure why. You guys have any idea?

Comment: why are you declaring both the ivar and property?

Comment: @Nick umm, it was already like that. I inherited the code from someone.

Comment: I'd delete the ivar declaration, and allow xcode to automatically synthesize the property to `_userId`. It avoids the name conflict and you can still get to the ivar if you need to. There is a good chance one of those declarations was in error.

Comment: @Nick yes. that's what i did. I removed the ivar and it's solved the problem.