# [CFNumber retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error every time I trigger a certain segue in my app. Thanks to these two links, I learned you can trouble shoot EXC_BAD_ACCESS easier after enabling  `NSZombies`.

[How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

I am using this app adhoc and testing it adhoc. http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

When the app loads, a UIScrollView with pictures are shown. When you tap a picture, a push segue is triggered to the fullscreen shot of that picture. The app runs perfectly on iPad but on my iPhone 4 it crashes every time before the push segue. Ive been stuck on this for a week. I just found out what NSZombies are and how to enable them: after I enable them the dubber reads as follows:

```
2015-07-03 22:26:36.170 iReporter[1878:60b] *** -[CFNumber retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x172e6210
```

[image: Screen shot of the debugger after the picture is tapped that causes crash (after enable NSZombies)]

After learning how to input 'bt' into the debugger out put to get more info, this is what the debugger reads now;

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x7246e, 0x2f1e515c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 540, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
* frame #0: 0x2f1e515c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 540
frame #1: 0x2f134768 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
frame #2: 0x2f11e5a8 CoreFoundation`+[__NSDictionaryM __new:::::] + 536
frame #3: 0x2f1212f0 CoreFoundation`-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 240
frame #4: 0x2f125dcc CoreFoundation`+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 372
frame #5: 0x000c96a4 iReporter`-[StreamPhotoScreen viewDidLoad](self=0x172e7560, _cmd=0x32053af3) + 256 at StreamPhotoScreen.m:20
frame #6: 0x31a044aa UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 518
frame #7: 0x31a04268 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 24
frame #8: 0x31b9036a UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 634
frame #9: 0x31aadd62 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 418
frame #10: 0x31aadb6c UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
frame #11: 0x31aadb04 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 184
frame #12: 0x319ffd58 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 380
frame #13: 0x3167d62a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
frame #14: 0x31678e3a QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
frame #15: 0x31678ccc QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
frame #16: 0x316786de QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 230
frame #17: 0x316784ee QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
frame #18: 0x31a033e0 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 8232
frame #19: 0x2f1ae20a CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
frame #20: 0x2f1ad6da CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
frame #21: 0x2f1abece CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 622
frame #22: 0x2f116ebe CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
frame #23: 0x2f116ca2 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
frame #24: 0x3401c662 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
frame #25: 0x31a6314c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
frame #26: 0x000c699c iReporter`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d44cec) + 108 at main.m:16
(lldb)
```

If i need to post more code/info it might be this: (section of code that the editor highlights on crash sometimes as well telling me its EXC_BAD_ACCESS_)

```
[api commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"stream", @"command", IdPhoto,@"IdPhoto", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
```

All I am trying to do is call the above data using j son and load it via a push segue. It works absolutely fine on iPad but crashes every time on iPhone 4?

Comment: Have you found any solution of how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Find the NSNumber property declaration,and check if you have wrongly give a type of `assign`.